# How to include a specific header file without having a conflict

Tags: c, compilation, header

My Files are

`main.c`

```
#include"A.h"
#include"B.h"
```

`A.c`

```
#include"A.h"
```

`B.c`

```
#include"B.h"
```

I have a file with a couple of structures that I have defined that I am supposed to use in all the files i.e `A.c , B.c, main.c` and even the header files for `A and B`.

Hence I  have

`A.h` and `B.h` both have

```
#include"struct.h"
```

Now, I see that in my main.c

I will have multiple declaration for both the structures, how do I get rid of this problem. What shall I change in my structure?

Thanks

Comment: You do have guard-fences in your header files to prevent the very multiple declarations your worried about, right?

Comment: Read about [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: @WhozCraig I am not sure what that is?

Comment: @Kraken you have a load of examples below that will show you what they are. Or look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files), or any of about three dozen similar posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use include guards.

aheader.h:

```
#ifndef AHEADER_H
#define AHEADER_H

// ... rest of header here

#endif
```

bheader.h:

```
#ifndef BHEADER_H
#define BHEADER_H

// ... rest of header here

#endif
```

Comment: And of course doing the same in the `structs.h` header file (or any other header file).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Shall I be doing this for each file ( I  guess I shall to make sure that none of the declaration duplicates), but if I take my case, then I guess only struct.h should have these guards, right?
Since that is the only declaration susceptible to duplicate?

Comment: @svk `aheader.h` has `struct.h` and `bheader.h` also has `struct.h`. So both `aheader.h` and `bheader.h` will be included and hence `struct.h` will also get included twice??

Comment: @Kraken You should make it a habit of doing it for all header files.

Comment: duly noted. Thanks people.
Been confused over it for quite sometime now. 
Cheers.

Comment: @Kraken I think in this case it is enough to do it only for struct.h, but for the long run just do it always like Jo means

Answer (score 1):

You can use a guard as such,

```
#ifndef MY_STRUCT
#define MY_STRUCT
#include "struct.h"
#endif
```

If you want to selectively take care of which parts should not be duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the header files in [include guards.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), like this:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

    // your definitions

#endif
```

Each header file should have its own guard with an unique name. The above preprocessor directives translated to english say something like: "If `MYHEADER_H` is not defined, then define it and paste the contents until `#endif` directive." This guarantees that a single header is included only once inside a single translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use so called `header guard` to be sure of including "struct.h" only once:

```
// struct.h
#ifndef STRUCT_H
#define STRUCT_H

struct ...{

}

#endif
```