# include period in header file name

Tags: c++

Sorry for what is probably an asinine question. I'm relatively inexperienced in C++ and I'm writing a small program with a header file. My cpp and h filenames have a period in them, for example: "**file_ver_1.1.cpp**" and "**file_ver_1.1.h**"

In my header file I have the following code

```
#ifndef FILE_VER_1.1_H_
#define FILE_VER_1.1_H_
... some code
#endif
```

I get a warning from the compiler saying "*extra tokens at end of #ifndef directive*" for the first line and "*missing whitespace after the macro name*" for the define line. **Is my header file name invalid because of the underscores and/or periods?** I've read these two articles but I didn't really understand them and I'm still confused:

```
    http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html#Macros
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't actually have version info in your file names, do you?

Comment: Seeing as this is a rather basic question, you might want to check out SO's [list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: You header file name is *not* invalid, but this really does not have anything to do with the name of the header file, just how you have written the include guard.

Comment: A macro name must be an identifier. Identifiers are not arbitrary strings; they may contain underscores, but they may not contain periods. Specifically, an identifier consists of a letter or underscore followed by zero or more letters, underscores, or digits. Identifiers starting with underscores are reserved for use by the implementation (though it's slightly more complicated than that).

Comment: @JustSide is version info in file names a no-no?

Comment: @crashmstr does the include guard not have to match the header file name?

Comment: @navr91 An include guard has to be unique to the file. If you used an MD5 hash of the filename (prefixed with a character in case it starts with a digit), it would work just as well. As long as you use a valid identifier unique to each header file, you can make your include guards anything you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is, your header file is indeed invalid (and even if it weren't, it woudln't be doing what you though it were). A period is not a valid identifier character, so the macro name is just `FILE_VER_1`.

When using include guard macros, you have to devise a scheme of "translating" filename characters which are not legal identifier characters. You could, for example, use `_P_` to represent a period. So your include guard would then be:

```
#ifndef FILE_VER_1_P_1_H_
#define FILE_VER_1_P_1_H_

//...

#endif
```

How exactly you do that is up to you (any other convention is OK), as long as it produces a legal identifier. And you should be consistent.