# Object listed in header file, yet undefined reference in cpp file

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue, undefined-reference

In the class, in my header file, in the private section of the class I have

```
 Heap_PriorityQueue<Passenger> oldBoardingQueue;
```

I have `#include "Heap_PriorityQueue.h"` in both the header and the cpp just to be safe.
I haven't even started using it in my cpp file, yet when I try to compile the cpp file throws up a bunch of:

```
undefiend reference to 'Heap_PriorityQueue<Passenger>::(insert function for Heap_PriorityQueue class isEmpty, add, etc.)
```

Followed by several

```
undefined reference to 'non-virtual thunk to Heap_PriorityQueue<Passenger>::(Heap_PriorityQueue functions again)
```

Unsure of how to proceed. Am I declaring incorrectly?

Edit:

Passenger is another class for creating Passenger objects holding the passenger's data (name, row, priority/key, etc).

Not sure what's meant by 'linker command' (I'm a student/newb) but the makefile for airworthy.cpp and airworthy.h files are as follows:

```
Airworthy.o: Airworthy.cpp Airworthy.h  Heap_PriorityQueue.h NotFoundException.h PrecondViolatedExcep.h Passenger.h
g++ -std=gnu++11 -ggdb -c Airworthy.cpp
```

Airworthy.h is as follows:

```
#ifndef AIRWORTHY_H
#define AIRWORTHY_H

#include "Heap_PriorityQueue.h"
#include "Passenger.h"

using namespace std;

class Airworthy
{
private:

    int oldBoardingSeconds;
    int randomBoardingSeconds;
    Heap_PriorityQueue<Passenger> oldBoardingQueue;
    Heap_PriorityQueue<Passenger> randomBoardingQueue;
    Passenger thisPassenger;

public:

    Airworthy();
    void inputFileData(ifstream& inputFile);
    void loadQueue(ifstream& inputFile, ofstream& outputFile);
    void runSim();
    void setOldBoardingPriority();
    void setRandomBoardingPriority();
};

#endif
```

Just realized that the error hones in on the first use of the Airworthy constructor which I've just had empty for now. Here's the first part of Airworthy.cpp

```
#include "Airworthy.h"
#include "Heap_PriorityQueue.h"
#include "Passenger.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


Airworthy::Airworthy()
{
}
```

Tried putting different things inside the constructor (including the Heap_PriorityQueues) but doesn't seem to make a difference. Calling the constructor in the main cpp file makes that file also generate the same errors.

Heap_PriorityQueue.h is as follows:

```
#ifndef _HEAP_PRIORITY_QUEUE
#define _HEAP_PRIORITY_QUEUE

#include "ArrayMaxHeap.h"
#include "PriorityQueueInterface.h"

template<class ItemType>
class Heap_PriorityQueue : public PriorityQueueInterface<ItemType>,
private ArrayMaxHeap<ItemType>
{
public:
   Heap_PriorityQueue();
   bool isEmpty() const;
   bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
   bool remove();

   /** @pre The priority queue is not empty. */
   ItemType peek() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
}; // end Heap_PriorityQueue


#endif
```

I'm at my wits end, I've been trying to make this damned thing work for hours now.

Comment: Could you please show a (preferably small) example of code reproducing the behaviour in question?

Comment: Also, because this sounds like a linking problem, please give us your linker command.

Comment: Or maybe your template class methods are defined in a .cpp (a [major C++ crime](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl))?

Comment: Do you include the header file where class Passenger API resides?

Comment: Since you mentioned including `Heap_PriorityQueue.h` into *both* you header and cpp file - are you using [include guards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files)? I remember having a problem with cyclic including without include guards when I didn't know I need to use them, and your problems seems similar to mine.

Comment: do you have a Heap_PriorityQueue.cpp?

Comment: Heap_PriorityQueue.cpp and Heap_PriorityQueue.h were both provided by the text and are in the same folder as the rest of the files.

Comment: It's been hours and I'm still having this error. I've even shifted Code::Blocks to use my custom makefile and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the likely problem is that you forgot to include `Heap_PriorityQueue.cpp` in the makefile recipe for  `Airworthy.o`. So the compiler is finding the definitions for the functions of the queue, but not the funtions themselves (that is the meaning of "undefined reference" in the linking stage)

EDIT: check if the build process produces a `Heap_PriorityQueue.o` file, and if this file is included in the final commandline that creates the exe.

Comment: Good idea so I gave it a shot. It didn't work but thank you anyways

Comment: @MKWhit OK, I expanded on my answer