# C++ include and redefinition of class error

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I am currently programming a program which searches song according to diffrent 
parameters.
In my system there are 2 types of songs: lyric and instrumetal.
Since i need to put both of them in 1 vector, I have a song class and
a LyricsSong & InstrumentalSong subclasses.

So I there is a Song.h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Song
{
public:
    std::string title;
    virtual void print();
    virtual void printSong(std::string query);
};
```

and there are the instrumental and lyrics subclasses, which are defined this way:

```
class LyricsSong : public Song
class InstrumentalSong : public Song
```

both of the include Song.h, and in both of them the class is defines 
only in the header file.

when I try to run another file which use the both subclasses,
and includes:

```
#include "LyricsSong.h"
#include "InstrumentalSong.h"
```

(and obviously more cpp libraries), i get the following compilation error:

```
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Users/Username/Documents/C++ Workshop/ex2/ex2_code/InstrumentalSong.h:16:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/Username/Documents/C++ Workshop/ex2/ex2_code/songsParser.cpp:26:
/cygdrive/c/Users/Username/Documents/C++ Workshop/ex2/ex2_code/Song.h:6:7: error: redefinition of 'class Song'
 class Song
       ^
In file included from /cygdrive/c/Users/Username/Documents/C++ Workshop/ex2/ex2_code/LyricsSong.h:15:0,
                 from /cygdrive/c/Users/Username/Documents/C++ Workshop/ex2/ex2_code/songsParser.cpp:25:
/cygdrive/c/Users/Username/Documents/C++ Workshop/ex2/ex2_code/Song.h:6:7: error: previous definition of 'class Song'
 class Song
       ^
```

when:

- lines InstrumentalSong.h:16:0 and LyricsSong.h:15:0 are where i
  include "Song.h"
- lines songsParser.cpp:25 and songsParser.cpp:26 are    where i
  include InstrumentalSong.h and LyricsSong.h
- line Song.h:6:7:    is    the defination of Song.h (where it's say's
  class Song, as showed       above).

What should I do?
P.S. I do not import any cpp file ever, only header files.

Comment: You are missing include guards: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files/1653965?s=2|0.0000#1653965

Comment: my problem is too many definitions, not missing ones, and i don't know how to use them in this kind of case.

Comment: I wasn't talking about missing definitons, but missing include guards. Did you even read the link?

Answer (score 13):

You have to tell preprocessor to include your header files only once. You can achieve by adding `#pragma once` on the top of all `*.h` files:

```
#pragma once

//Your header file's code
```

It is also a good practice to always begin header files with this line.

Comment: `#pragma once` is not standard, and it can not work in some situations. It was explicitly not standardized because of those (not portably solvable) problems. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard/1946730#1946730) for some issues.

Comment: But it actually solved my problem. I spent around an hour searching for a solution and this^ solved it.

But why does it have that one drawback?

Answer (score 5):

They both include 'Song.h' file and preprocessor takes the file content twice.
You need to write 'LyricsSong.h' and 'InstrumentalSong.h' file contents inside #ifndef #define and #endif directives. Like this

```
#ifndef LYRICS_SONG_H
#define LYRICS_SONG_H

your code goes here.
...

#endif
```

Comment: In most compilers you can use more efficent #pragma once also

Comment: @DawidPi I don't like to use tools/features which is non-standard and don't suggest anyone to do so.

Comment: Most importantly, he needs to put an include guard into `Song.h`. Putting it into `LyricsSong.h` and `InstrumentalSong.h` is good practice, but not enough.

Comment: I uderstand this in fact, I also prefer standard solutions but #pragma once is available in every modern compiler. msvs,gcc,clang or whatever. And if you have lot's of files it can reduce compile time significantly

Comment: At least for gcc `#pragma once` is probably no more efficient than the standard include guards, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/cpp/Once_002dOnly-Headers.html#Once_002dOnly-Headers). Other compilers probably have similar optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, I would also use #pragma once, it is more convenient and clean. But be aware that it is not a C++ standard, so it can be a problem if you have to use different compilers (although it is a wide-spread extension).