# Why #define a empty macro?

Tags: c

Why sometimes I see

```
#define __Empty_macro__
```

in C? What is the usage of it? For example:

```
#ifndef _BUILDIN_H_
#define _BUILDIN_H_

//codes never used _BUILDIN_H_ ...

#endif /* _BUILDIN_H_ */
```

For example, [here is the source code of a shell](https://github.com/dingdongnigetou/shell/blob/master/include/build_in.h).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are #ifndef and #define used in c++ header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files) Edit: the question was originally tagged c++ as well. The answer to the question is identical for c++ and c as far as I am aware, and has already answered in the duplicate.

Comment: well i call those undefined behavior

Comment: @user3528438, and you call those undefined behavior based on what?

Comment: @StoryTeller underscores

Answer (score 8):

Because an "empty macro" still exists and it is possible to check if they exist using `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`.

Typically, this behavior is used to prevent multiple copies of the same header being included (aka "include guards", which is what your example is). However, it can also be used to conditionally include certain portions of a program.

Sometimes, macros like `NDEBUG` or `_DEBUG` merely being defined can change program output, such as by including more expensive runtime checks which would be undesirable in the final product, but could help track bugs during development.

Custom "empty" defines can be used similarly to include or exclude certain binary functionality from the program build. This could be done for performance (removing logging), security (removing sensitive parts of the program), business reasons (some features might require more expensive versions of the program), and so on.

Comment: They also provide a convenient fallback when there is no meaningful expansion. For instance when attempting to define a portable `DLL_EXPORT` specification for your headers.

Answer (score 5):

There are different reasons for using them.
For example if need to include some library just once. You could define a macro. Then you check if that macro has been defined so you skip the inclusion. And so on.

Here there is an explanation about: [inclusion guard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Answer (score 4):

In the `C` and `C++` programming languages, an `#include` guard, sometimes called a `macro guard`, is a particular construct used to avoid the problem of `double inclusion` when dealing with the include directive. The addition of #include guards to a header file is one way to make that file idempotent. For example, Consider you want to include `grandfather.h` and `father.h` header files in `child.h` file.

**File "grandfather.h"**

```
#ifndef GRANDFATHER_H
#define GRANDFATHER_H

struct foo {
   int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDFATHER_H */
```

**File "father.h"**

```
#include "grandfather.h"
```

**File "child.c"**

```
#include "grandfather.h"
#include "father.h"
```

Here, the first inclusion of `"grandfather.h"` causes the macro `GRANDFATHER_H` to be defined. Then, when "child.c" includes "grandfather.h" the second time (as `father.h` also includes `grandfather.h`) by including `father.h`, the `#ifndef` test returns false, and the preprocessor skips down to the #endif of the file `grandfather.h`, thus avoiding the second definition of struct foo. And the program compiles correctly.