# C++: Getting multiple "multiple definition of" errors when compiling

Tags: c++, oop

I'm new to classes and object-oriented programming. Our instructor is having us create a program that must have a `.cpp` file, a main `.cpp` file, and a `.hpp` file.

Here are each of the files:

First, the `odometer.hpp` file:

```
class Odometer
{
    int miles;
    float gallons, mpg;

public:
    //Constructors
    Odometer(); //Default
    Odometer(float g, int m); 

    //Mutator Functions
    void Set_miles(int m);
    void Set_gallons(float g);

    //Functions
    void Add_trip(int m, float g);
    int Check_mileage(float g);
    void Print_info();

    //Accessor Functions
    float Get_mpg();
    float Get_gallons();
    int Get_miles();
};
```

Next, the `odometer.cpp` file:

```
#include "odometer.hpp"
#include <iostream>

//Constructors
Odometer::Odometer()
{
    miles = 0;
    gallons = 0.0;
    mpg = 0.0;
}

Odometer::Odometer(float g, int m)
{
    miles = m;
    gallons = g;
    mpg = m / g;
}

//Mutator functions
void Odometer::Set_miles(int m)
{
    miles = m;
}

void Odometer::Set_gallons(float g)
{
    gallons = float(g);
}

//Accessor functions
float Odometer::Get_mpg()
{
    return mpg;
}

float Odometer::Get_gallons()
{
    return gallons;
}

int Odometer::Get_miles()
{
    return miles;
}

//Other functions
//Takes # of gallons & # of miles and adds it to previous values, calculating
//new miles/gallon for whole trip
void Odometer::Add_trip(int m, float g)
{
    miles += m;
    gallons += g;
    mpg = miles / gallons;
}

int Odometer::Check_mileage(float g)
{
    int newMiles = g * mpg;
    return newMiles;
}

void Odometer::Print_info()
{
    std::cout << "Miles:   " << miles << "     Gallons: " << gallons << 
"     Miles/Gallon: " << mpg;
}
```

And finally, the `odometer_main.cpp` file (so far, it's incomplete):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "odometer.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    //Odometer odDefault; //Odometer object set to defaults
    Odometer od(10, 100); //Odometer object with values set
    return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting when I try compiling all the files:

```
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Odometer()':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Odometer()'  
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Odometer()':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Odometer()'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Odometer(float, int)':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0x30): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Odometer(float, int)'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0x30): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Odometer(float, int)':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0x30): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Odometer(float, int)'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0x30): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Set_miles(int)':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0x72): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Set_miles(int)'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0x72): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Set_gallons(float)':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0x8a): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Set_gallons(float)'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0x8a): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Get_mpg()':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0xa8): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Get_mpg()'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0xa8): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Get_gallons()':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0xbc): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Get_gallons()'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0xbc): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Get_miles()':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0xd0): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Get_miles()'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0xd0): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Add_trip(int, float)':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0xe0): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Add_trip(int, float)'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0xe0): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Check_mileage(float)':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0x140): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Check_mileage(float)'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0x140): first defined here
/tmp/ccArjYHP.o: In function 'Odometer::Print_info()':
odometer_main.cpp:(.text+0x168): multiple definition of 'Odometer::Print_info()'
/tmp/cc1W9Ght.o:odometer.cpp:(.text+0x168): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:2: recipe for target 'odometer' failed
make: *** [odometer] Error 1
```

Comment: change `#include "odometer.cpp"` to `#include "odometer.hpp"`

Comment: Agreed. Why'd you add that, anyway?

Comment: Our instructor told us to do it like that, and even included it like that in the example files.

Comment: You want to include the header file, not the source file.

Comment: @CodyT96 your examples are incorrect then. Or are for some very, very, very specific situation.

Comment: Well, that seemed to have fixed everything. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

In short, replace `#include "odometer.cpp"` with `#include "odometer.hpp"`. Now for the why.

Your program consists of source files like `main.cpp` and `odometer.cpp`. These files contain definitions for functions, variables, or classes in your project. Your compiler compiles each source file (`.cpp`) separately into object files (`.o`), and then your linker links these object files together to form your program.

However, although your source files are compiled separately, they will need to interact with each other. `main.cpp` will want to create `Odometer` objects and access `Odometer` member functions and so on. So we need a way to tell `main.cpp` what an `Odometer` is. The easiest way to do that is to define `Odometer` in a header file, and `#include` that header in `main.cpp`.

`#include` is a *preprocessor directive* that inserts the contents of another file into the current file. The preprocessor runs before your code is actually compiled. The idea is that you have some declarations in a file, which we call a header file, and multiple source files that need access to those declarations. So each source file will `#include` the header.

Note though that `main.cpp` doesn't need access to the *definitions* of `Odometer`'s member functions, it just needs to know what those functions are and how to call them. That information is in the class definition in `odometer.hpp`, not in `odometer.cpp`. It would be an error to `#include "odometer.cpp"`, because then we would have functions that are defined in two different places, and the linker will complain.

So in general you put your class definition in a header file (`.hpp`), put the class implementation in a source file (`.cpp`), and `#include` the header file in any other source file that needs access to that class. If you structure your programs correctly in this way, you should never need to `#include` a `.cpp` file into another `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1):

The are multiple problems here:

**odometer.hpp**

- `Odometer(float g, int m)`: This is not defined in `odometer.cpp`
- `Odometer()` : This default constructor should also be defined in `odometer.cpp`
- Odometer has three member variables but only two are taken as input, it is unclear how the third `mpg` is initialized
- There are no include guards in your header file

  `#ifdef ODO_H`

  `#define ODO_H`

  `class Odometer{`
   `// your class declaration`
  `};`

  `#endif`

**odometer.cpp**

- `#include "odometer.hpp"`
- `#include <iostream>` - since you are using `std::cout`
- Provide definitions for various `Odometer` constructors.

**main.cpp**

- `#include "odometer.hpp"` - since you are using Odometer class here

Solving these issues should help you compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are including your odometer.cpp into your odometer_main.cpp, you can't also compile separately your odometer.cpp and link it with your odometer_main.cpp. In that case, yeah, you will get duplicate symbols. The typical way, though, is to only include the .hpp file into your main, and all else should compile and link fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to used file exclusion directives to avoid multiple inclusion.

```
#ifndef ODOMETER_H
#define ODOMETER_H
#include "odometer.h"
#endif
```

Have a look at this question:

[Why are #ifndef and #define used in c++ header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files)

Also as the guys commented, you should include the h file