# How can I check if a struct type has been defined before?

Tags: c

I need to define all structs in one head file but how can I do that, in order to avoid the redefinition of typedef error !

Comment: Hmmm ... define/declare them in alphabetical order?

Comment: What "redefinition of typedef error"? Are you talking about structs or typedefs?

Comment: Do you mean, when the file is included you get errors because the structs are re-defined? If that's what you mean take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653958/why-are-ifndef-and-define-used-in-c-header-files)

Comment: Why and how are you getting redefinition errors?  Post some actual code that demonstrates those errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean that you want to separate your program file into one header file that declares the struct you need and one program file that include your program?

create a file named "type.h", and in this file

```
/* type.h */
#ifndef TYPE_H
#define TYPE_H
typedef struct t_Node
{
  int m_Info;
}t_Node;

/* ... definition of another struct */
#endif
```

and in the file that includes your program, for example, "main.c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  "type.h"
int main(void)
{
  /* your program */
}
```

and you need to put the two files in one directory. Or you need to use `gcc -c main.c -I <directory of type.h>`

Comment: Yes this is what I need thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the redefinition of elements with multiple header inclusions, you can use the preprocessor macros `#ifndef` and `#define` to only define once each value.