# C - Typedef redefinition with different types

Tags: c, struct, include, header-files

Let's take an example of my project:

I have 2 files, **file1.c** and **file2.c**. Both of these files have a header file (**file1.h** and **file2.h**). I also have a **struct.h** file which contains:

```c
typedef struct {
    char region[80];
    int startDate;
    int endDate;
    int startTime;
    int endTime;
} Schedule;
```

Both of the header files (**file1.h** and **file2.h**) include **struct.h** and the **main.c** includes both **file1.h** and **file2.h**. Let's say this is the **main.c**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main() {
    /* function from file1.h */
    int num1 = sum(1, 3);

    /* function from file2.h */
    int num2 = mul(4, 5);
}
```

Now, in **main.c** I get the error: `In included file: typedef redefinition with different types`. I assume the error is because both **file1.h** and **file2.h** declare their own common structs from **struct.h**.

Any ideas on a solution for the problem?

Comment: Use include guards. That's the standard approach to preventing multiple include issues. Looking to see if I can find a duplicate. If not, your test book should certainly discuss them.

Comment: [This post might help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1653958/631266)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to deal with this issue is to enclose the definitions in `struct.h` inside a `#if` or `#ifdef` preprocessor directive to avoid duplicate definitions if the file is included more than once. This is commonly referred to as **include guards**.

**struct.h**:

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H_INCLUDED
#define STRUCT_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct {
    char region[80];
    int startDate;
    int endDate;
    int startTime;
    int endTime;
} Schedule;

#endif /* STRUCT_H_INCLUDED */
```

You should use this method on all include files to prevent redundant definitions which cause compilation errors in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common issue when include other file unites, and the solution is to always use include guards in your header file, e.g.

```
// struct.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_STRUCT_H
#define INCLUDED_STRUCT_H

typedef struct {
  char region[80];
  int startDate;
  int endDate;
  int startTime;
  int endTime;
} Schedule;

#endif
```

With this include guard, in your `main.c`, even it includes both `file1.h` and `file2.h`, there is only definition of the `struct`.