# Forward declaration with friend function: invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, friend-function

```
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A{
 int a;
public:
 friend void B::frndA();
};

class B{
 int b;
public:
 void frndA();
};

void B::frndA(){
 A obj;
 std::cout << "A.a = " << obj.a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
 return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile this code, some errors occurred. E.g.

> invalid use of incomplete type

What are the problems in this code?

Comment: I've retagged the question. `friend` isn't one of the most helpful keywords. Also `forward-declaration` makes more sense when combined in one tag. Edit: Oh and `class` also makes more sense then `function` I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the whole of the `class B ...` declaration before `class A`. You haven't declared `B::frndA();` yet.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B{
    int b;
public:
    void frndA();
};

class A{
    int a;
public:
    friend void B::frndA();
};



void B::frndA(){
    A obj;
    //cout<<"A.a = "<<obj.a<<endl;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you can't friend a member function before the compiler has seen the declaration.

You are going to need to rearrange your code to solve the problem (i.e. move the definition of `class B` prior to `class A`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the declaration of `B` before `A`.  The compiler doesn't know about this: `B::frndA()`.  A forward declaration is not enough information to infer what members the type has.

I would recommend to put your class `A` declaration in a file `A.h` and it's definition inside a file `A.cpp`.  Likewise the same for the type `B` inside of `B.h` and `B.cpp`

At the top of each header file put `#pragma once` (or if you prefer include guards).

Then inside your `B.h` you can simply include `A.h`.

Comment: In fact, pragma once can fail when the same file falls within different search paths since it's based on the path and not on the content of the file.

Comment: pragma once is supported by all major compilers.  I don't think #pragma once warrants the down vote.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards/1143958#1143958