# Member Function as Friend: Is the book Lippman 5th wrong?

Tags: c++

Lippman 5th
ISBN-13: 978-0321714114

Page 280-281, it says:

> **Making A Member Function a Friend**
>
> Rather than making the entire  Window_mgr class a friend, Screen can
>   instead specify that only the clear member is allowed  access. When we
>   declare a member function to be a friend, we must specify the class of
>   which that function is a member:
>
> ```
> class Screen {
>     // Window_mgr::clear must have been declared before class Screen
>     friend void Window_mgr::clear(ScreenIndex);
>     // ... rest of the Screen class
> };
> ```
>
> Making a member function a friend requires careful structuring of our
>   programs to accommodate interdependencies among the declarations and
>   definitions. In this example, we must order our program as follows:
>
> - First, define the Window_mgr class, which declares, but cannot define, clear. Screen must be declared before clear can use the
>     members of Screen.
> - Next, define class Screen, including a friend declaration for clear.
> - Finally, define clear, which can now refer to the members in Screen.

The problem is: class Window_mgr has a data member that depends of class
Screen definition. See:

```
class Window_mgr {
public:
    // location ID for each screen on the window
    using ScreenIndex = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    // reset the Screen at the given position to all blanks
    void clear(ScreenIndex);
private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens{Screen(24, 80, ' ')};
};
```

So it is impossible firstly define Window_mgr without defining Screen
previously!
And at the same time, it is impossible define Screen without we have
defined Window_mgr!!!

How can this problem be solved???
Is the book wrong?

I will paste here a code so that you can repeat the problem using a
minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A
{
    friend void B::hello();

public:
    A(int i) : number{i} {}

private:
    void f() {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
    int number;
};

class B {
private:
    std::vector<A> x{A(10)};

public:
    void hello()
    {
        for(A &elem : x)
        {
            elem.f();
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    A x;

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this code, the result is:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'B'
     friend void B::hello();

And if I invert the position (A <--> B), I have:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'A'
     std::vector x{A(10)};

Is there a correct way to do that??

Thank you!

---

EDIT:

Thank you, Craig Young

Solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A;

class B {
private:
    std::vector<A> x;

public:
    B();
    void hello();

};

class A
{
    friend void B::hello();

public:
    A(int i) : number{i} {}

private:
    void f() {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
    int number;
};

B::B() : x{A(10)}
{

}

void B::hello()
{
    for(A &elem : x)
    {
        elem.f();
    }
}

int main()
{


    return 0;
}
```

Conclusion:

- the book is incomplete in that it doesn't expose the necessity of doing the forward declaration of class A firstly and the impossibility to do in-class initialization in this case.
- I didn't notice that the problem was the A(10), not the vector! That is, we can use incomplete type A (only declaration, without definition) when we are using it as Template argument to vector (because it doesn't create A object itself) but we can not use incomplete type A when defining a object, for example: A(10);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For a start

Well, you're not following the guidance correctly.

> First, define the Window_mgr class, which declares, but cannot define, clear. Screen must be declared before clear can use the members of Screen.

You must declare `B` before `A`.

> Next, define class Screen, including a friend declaration for clear.

Now declare `A` with `B::hello()` as a friend.

> Finally, define clear, which can now refer to the members in Screen.

`B:hello()` can use the private members of `A`.

This has been covered before here: [C++ Forward declaration , friend function problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3183710/224704)

### You've added complications

Furthermore you want declarations of `B` to reference `A`. To achieve this you need to forward declare `A` so that `B` knows of its existence.

***And*** it's important to be aware that you have only "partial" access to `A`. You cannot 'fully use' `A` in the declaration of `B`. So the following line in `B` is wrong.

```
//You're trying to create A when you only know it exists.
//You don't have a full definition of A yet.
std::vector<A> x{A(10)};

//Replace the above with...
std::vector<A> x;
```

*Of course you'll have to find another way to initialise `x`.*

---

### Sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A;

class B
{
private:
    std::vector<A> x;
public:
    void hello();
};

class A
{
    friend void B::hello();
public:
    A(int i): number(i) {}

private:
    void f() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
    int number;
};

void B::hello()
{     
    for(A &elem : x)
    {
        elem.f();
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a{5};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to declare B before A, but I didn't notice that the problem was the A(10), not the vector<A>! That is, we can use incomplete type A (only declaration, without definition) when are using it as Template argument to vector (because it doesn't create A object itself) but we can not use incomplete type A when defining a object, for example: A u;

Comment: I will edit my question and accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: I disagree with you when you say that I've added complications. See the line std::vector<Screen> screens{Screen(24, 80, ' ')};

Comment: That is, the book is incomplete in that it doesn't expose the necessity of doing the forward declaration of class A and the impossibility to do in-class initialization in this case. My Edit corrects the two problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an earlier *declaration*, but not an earlier *definition*.

Adding

```
class A;
class B;
```

at the front tells the compiler that “A” and “B” refer to classes.  That should be enough for it to reason out the rest.

Comment: This solution doesn't work: error: incomplete type 'B' named in nested name specifier
    friend void B::hello();

Comment: You have additional problems in the A/B example beyond friendless, because you’re including the body of the methods so you need implementation details rather than just the class signatures. This is why classes usually have their signatures defined in a header file.

Comment: If I remove the body of the methods I still have the data member std::vector<A> x{A(10)} to solve. The book ignored this problem.

Comment: The data member itself is fine, it’s the core call to give it a value that’s a circular reference. Put that in the ctor body, provided after the class signature.