# What's difference between #pragma and #ifndef?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [#pragma once vs include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards)

When should I use `#pragma once`?

When should I use `#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED`?

Answer (score 15):

The #ifndef/#define/#endif trick works on any C compiler, and on some of them it speeds up the compilation process. The #pragma trick is non-standards, and only works on few C compilers, and may result in different semantics in those that do not support it.

Comment: Note though, that it's supported on the big three: GCC, MSVC, and ICC.

Comment: Even if it were supported by all but one, it would still be stupid to use it since there's a trivial method (the `#ifndef` one) which works on all compilers and is universally familiar to anyone who knows C.

Comment: @R: Unless you (and maybe your team, whom is all using the same compiler) is the only one on the project. I've had problems in the past where I'd rename a header file but forget to update the `#ifndef`. Or if that particular constant accidentally gets copied.

Comment: @Mark: feel free to use a UUID or just some random string followed by the exact date and time the header was originally created instead of the filename in the `#ifndef`. There's no excuse for `#pragma once`.

Comment: Even if you your team's current compilers support a non-standard extension, will your future ones do? That's the risky bit about non-standard stuff.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that the latter is C and the former is not. Never use `#pragma once`; always use `#ifndef`.

One other thing to note when using the `#ifndef` method is that any preprocessor symbol beginning with two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital letter is **reserved and cannot be used**. You should use things like `#ifndef MYHEADER_H` and **not** `#ifndef _MYHEADER_H`.

Comment: Strictly, `#pragma` is C; there are even some standard pragmas.  You would be correct if you said "Don't use `#pragma once`", though.

Comment: But `#pragma once` is not C. It's an implementation-defined use of `#pragma`.

Comment: The point I'm making is that your statement 'Never use `#pragma`' is an over-statement; there are legitimate and C99 standard uses for Standard C pragmas - specifically,`#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT ON` is a perfectly standard and valid use of `#pragma`.  However, as I said previously, stating that `#pragma once` is not standard and is best not used would be correct.

Comment: I meant to say "Never use `#pragma once`". I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

The construct

#### myfoo.h

```
#ifndef MYFOO_H
#define MYFOO_H

/* header information for myfoo.h */

#endif
```

belongs in every header-file. The trick is: you can include a header file (accidentally) more than once without thinking abaout double declarations. so this is for the preprocessor.

The #pragma is for the compiler, and a preprocessor should ignore pragmas it does not understand.

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'accidentally'. It's more likely that header files B and C both depend on header file A and thus both include it. Then, if one source file includes both header files B and C, it will thereby include header file A twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#pragma` when you are addressing a **specific compiler** (or set of compatible compilers) to guide its code generation or if you are using a standardized `#pragma` like `FP_CONTRACT` or `-CX_LIMITED_RANGE-` that any standards-compliant compiler is going to support.

Use `#ifndef` and ilk if you are addressing the standard C (or C++) pre-processor and wish to have your code rendered portable across all standards-compliant compilers.

Use of any `#pragma` that is not defined in the C (or C++) standard renders your code non-portable.  `#pragma once` is a bit of an exception in that it is one of the most commonly-implemented of the non-standard `#pragma` constructs.  Its implementation, however, is not universal across standards-compliant compilers.  `#ifndef` is.