# What MSVC++ 2008 Express Editon compiler does and doesn't

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I've been wondering if the msvc++ 2008 compiler takes care of multiple header includes of the same file, considering this example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"
#include "header.h"
```

Will the compiler include this file multiple times or just one? (I'm aware I can use the #ifndef "trick" to prevent this from happening)
Also, if I include "header.h" which contains 10 functions, but I only call or use 2, will it still include all 10 or just the 2 I need and all of their needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the compiler (or, more accurately, the pre-processor) doesn't take care of this "automatically". Not in Visual C++ 2008, or in any other version. And you really wouldn't want it to.

There are two standard ways of going about this. You should choose one of them.

The first is known as **include guards**. That's the "`#ifndef` trick" you mentioned in your question. But it's certainly not a "trick". It's the standard idiom for handling this situation when writing C++ code, and any other programmer who looks at your source file will almost certainly *expect* to see include guards in there somewhere.

The other takes advantage of a VC++ feature (one that's also found its way into several other C++ toolkits) to do essentially the same thing in a way that's somewhat easier to type. By including the line `#pragma once` at the top of your header file, you instruct the pre-processor to only include the header file *once* per translation unit. This [has some other advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards) over include guards, but they're not particularly relevant here.

As for your second question, the *linker* will take care of "optimizing" out functions that you never call in your code. But this is the last phase of compilation, and has nothing to do with `#include`, which is handled by the pre-processor, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Alright, thanks :). So just to set things straight: to prevent multiple inclusions of the same header file I have to implement a so called 'include guard' (thanks for adding a new word to my "programmers dictionary" ;)) and the linker WILL remove "unnecessary" code from the final executable?

Comment: @Benjamin: Those two things are unrelated. Compilation in C++ occurs in several different stages. The `#include` directives are resolved by the pre-processor in the *first* stage of compilation. As Oli's answer suggests, it essentially copies-and-pastes the contents of the headers into your source files. That's why you need the include guards (or `#pragma once`) to prevent it from copying and pasting it more than once. At a *later* phase of compilation, called the **link stage**, the linker is going to see what functions you call and only include those that you actually use.

Comment: @Benjamin: Read the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work) to get a better understanding of how all the steps actually work.

Answer (score 4):

`#include` is basically a synonym for "copy-and-paste".  If you do identical `#include`s, the contents of that header file will be copy-and-pasted twice, sequentially.

As to your second question, it doesn't really make sense.  `#include`s are executed by the *preprocessor*, which runs before the *compiler* and the *linker*.  The preprocessor doesn't know or care what the content of the header file is, it simply copy-and-pastes it in.  The linker may be able to eliminate unnecessary functions, but that's completely independent of the preprocessor.

Comment: How can you be sure MSVC doesn't take care of this as some sort of preprocessing optimization? :)

Comment: @Armen: Well, I can't be sure!  But I can't imagine that it would do such a thing, because there are occasions where you really do want to `#include` something multiple times (e.g. X macros).

Answer (score 1):

The MSVC 20xx preprocessor (not the compiler -- the compiler never sees preprocessor directives) does not in any sense "take care of" multiple #includes of the same file. If a file is #included twice, the preprocessor obeys the #includes and includes the file two times. (Just imagine the chaos if the preprocessor even thought about trying to correct your source file's "bad" #include behavior.)

Because the preprocessor is so meticulous and careful about following your instructions, each #included file must protect itself from being #included twice. That protection is what we see when we find lines like these at the top of a header file:

```
 #ifndef I_WAS_ALREADY_INCLUDED   // if not defined, continue with include
 #define I_WAS_ALREADY_INCLUDED   // but make sure I'm not included again

    [ header-file real contents ]

 #endif  // I_WAS_ALREADY_INCLUDED
```

When you write a header file, you must always be sure to protect it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care? It doesn't add really much burden on the compiler because the compiler conditionally (with `#ifdef`s, for example) excludes code it doesn't need to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor will include 2 times these headers. Thats why guards in header files are required.
As far as I know the linker is most cases will remove code (functions) that are newer used to reduce executable file size.