# Single class has a Class Redefinition Error

Tags: c++, class, redefinition

I'm new to C++, and I'm having a problem with my class definitions in a header file.
The code for the header file (Student.h) is:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
  // Data Members for a Student
  string id;
  string preferences[3];
  int skill;

  // Constructor
 public:
  Student(){}

 public:
  void SetID(string str)
  { this->id = str; }
 public:
  void SetSkill(int i)
  { this->skill = i; }
 public:
  void SetPreferences(int i, string s)
  {
    this->preferences[i] = s;
  }
};

class StudentSchedule
{
 public:
  StudentSchedule(){}
};
```

The compiler error says that line 14 (class Student) is a redefinition of 'Student', and that line 15 ({ -- the open brace following class Student) is the previous definition of 'Student'.
The same error on the first two consecutive lines exists for the StudentSchedule class.

I have no .c, .cpp, or .h files anywhere in my compilation that define either class. I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need [**header guards**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) on that header file.  It is presumably being included twice.

Modify the header, adding these lines to the beginning and end.

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

// Put the entire contents of your header here...

#endif
```

The define doesn't need to be `STUDENT_H`... it just needs to be unique.

With these directives added, the compiler will ignore all contents of the header file if it has already been parsed.

**Alternatively**, while [it is not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936), all major compilers will allow you to put a single

```
#pragma once
```

as the first line of the header to prevent it from being parsed multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably including the .h file twice, the first time it will define Student, the second it will try to redefine it.

See the [Wikipedia entry on include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) for a more extensive explanation of the problem and information on how to avoid it.

In short, there are two ways to do it

Version 1, #defined include guards

```
#ifndef STUDENT_HPP
#define STUDENT_HPP

...your code here...

#endif
```

Usually the #define is called some variation of the file name since it has to be different in every include file.

Version 2, #pragma once

```
#pragma once

...your code here...
```

This pragma is (as most pragmas) not portable to all compilers, but [some of the most important ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability). It also has the advantage of not needing a manually assigned name.

Which you use is up to you, but you most likely have to pick one :)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using

```
   #pragma once
```

as the first line of a header file, instead of the defines. Even if this is non-standard, it does avoid name clashes and can reduce compile time.

Comment: It's nice (certainly simpler), but that's not standard C++

Comment: yes, that is the only drawback. For me, the advantages outweigh this.

Answer (score 0):

When I learnt c++ our professor said, the first two lines that you write in c++ class should always be #ifndef followed by #define. This prevents multiple definitions in header files

http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/preprocessor/ifdef.html