# Dll programming in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to run an application using dll. I am using Dev C++, but i always get a linker error.
The code of dll.h is

```
#ifndef _DLL_H_
#define _DLL_H_

#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#else 
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
#endif 


class DLLIMPORT sum
{
  public:
    sum();
    void input();
    void add();
    void display();
    virtual ~sum(void);

  private:
          int x,y,res;

};


#endif 

and that of dllmain.cpp is
#include<iostream>
#include "dll.h"
#include <windows.h>
sum::sum()
{
 x=y=res=0;
}


sum::~sum()
{
}
void sum::input()
{
     std::cout<<"Enter two numbers ";
     std::cin>>x>>y;
}
void sum::add()
{
     res=x+y;
}
void sum::display()
{
     std::cout<<"The application in running under a dll file"<<std::endl;
     std::cout<<"The sum is "<<res<<std::endl;
}              

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain (HINSTANCE hInst     /* Library instance handle. */ ,
                       DWORD reason        /* Reason this function is being called. */ ,
                       LPVOID reserved     /* Not used. */ )
{
    switch (reason)
    {
      case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        break;

      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;

      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;

      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    /* Returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure */
    return TRUE;
}
```

The host application (sample.cpp) code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include "dll.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    sum s;
    s.input();
    s.add();
    s.display();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But i get a linker error saying:

```
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3sumC1Ev@4' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3sum5inputEv@4' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3sum3addEv@4' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3sum7displayEv@4' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3sum7displayEv@4' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3sum7displayEv@4' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3sum7displayEv@4'
```

I dont know what to do. I just started dll programming, but am stick with this.
Can anybody help me out this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/673730

Comment: Formating this for you was more work than if you hadn't put your random `<code>` or `<br>`. Please read the faq and [the markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)  before asking again.

Comment: Macros and identifiers containing an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved by the implementation, change your header guards!

Comment: @rubenvb: Right, or just use a convenient `pragma once`.

Comment: @Mr.C64 which is equally nonstandard. No.

Comment: @rubenvb: `pragma once` is supported by MSVC, and I think also by GCC and Clang. I use it with MSVC. While `_RESERVED` (like `_Reserved`) is an abomination since underscore followed by capital letter is reserved, `pragma once` certainly isn't.

Comment: @Mr.C64 both are implementation defined behavior. Both non-standard, whichever way you put it. You don't even gain anything from pragma once, header guard handling is extremely optimized in modern compilers. But this is a boring discussion, so lets stop `;-)`

Comment: @rubenvb: `pragma once` is less error prone and more convenient to me; in any case, there are several discussions on this topic, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards).

Answer (score 0):

Your `DLLIMPORT` symbol is expand to `__declspec(dllexport)` if `BUILDING_DLL` is `#define`'d.

So, in your DLL implementationn file (`dllmain.cpp`), you should `#define` `BUILDING_DLL` *before* `#include "dll.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `DLLIMPORT` like this:

```
#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
#endif
```

But you've forgotten to define `BUILDING_DLL` in your dll source files, before the inclusion of `dll.h`:

```
#define BUILDING_DLL
#include "dll.h"
```

*Note*: you should use:

```
#ifdef BUILDING_DLL
```

instead of

```
#if BUILDING_DLL
```

because the first one is more self-documenting.