# Workaround for ifdef / ifndef

Tags: c++, class, templates, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I have a class `A`, and two classes, `B` and `C`, inheriting from `A`.

Apart from the methods from `A`, each class is to offer different things, and, therefore, I'd like to put them in two different files -- `b.hpp` and `c.hpp`, since they're templates with inline functions.

I also have a class `User`, using both `B` and `C` classes. In `user.cpp`, I should have something close to:

```
# include "b.hpp"
# include "c.hpp"

class User{
    ...;
};
```

Which would raise a compiler redefinition error, for what I'm keeping both classes `B` and `C` in a `bc.hpp`.

The concern here is rather aesthetic other than a programming error: I just don't find *very elegant* using `ifdef / ifndef` directives in small applications -- they always look to me like IDE's solution for people managing too many modules, and for those not even aware of the directives.

Is there any (*even nonstandard, but at least sane*) workaround for this, or do I have to stick with either having two different classes in the same file and using `ifdef / ifndef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifndef` really are good practice. They help you to make your files *header self-contained*.

You do not want some file `A` to stop compiling because you removed an `include` statement `C` somewhere in another file `B`. So for that matter, you include `C` in both `A` and `B`. Maybe `A` includes `B`, but it doesn't matter. Otherwise, you would have to add an `include C` in `B` whenever you remove `include C` from `A`.

So `ifndef` really are good practices and should be used. Depending on your compiler, you may have syntactic shortcuts such as [pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) (find a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards)) - but keep in mind it's not standard even if supported by most compilers.

Btw, professional production code does use `ifndef` guards.

Comment: I agree they're used by very professional people -- I've seen kernel code speaking `ifndef`'s once I had to open it ^^ It's just I'm used to avoid using it for too small applications, as the one I'm developing. Guess I'll have to accept the facts, anyway (: Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: @Rubens For a *really* small application, there's no requirement to use a header at all. But for now, header guards are how C++ achieves this kind of modularity.

Comment: My way of doing things is: keep the included headers as low as possible to improve compilation time, but always put safe-guards not to care about double nested includes.

Comment: @Mic This *not to care about ...* is exactly the reason why I both avoid this and I very often just compile my code after writing the whole thing. I go on playing lottery if I don't do so, as I let the compiler mind both my code and it's execution ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you mean in the header file, no, there is not a good, portable way to do this.  It is standard to keep all of your header files in the format -

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_HPP
#define MYHEADER_HPP

// ... content

#endif
```

Any other way would be nonstandard and not *real* C++.

Comment: The OP explicitly said that he's open to "nonstandard" solutions.

Comment: @CongXu Sorry, I've added it later, considering pyrospade's answer. I'm yet anxious to see if there's any other workaround for it (:

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [`#pragma once`](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7877/).