# How to use header files?

Tags: c++, header

I wanted to learn using header files. and I got an error. here is my code:

**printmyname.h:**

```
void printMyName();
```

**printmyname.cpp:**

```
#include "printmyname.h"

void printMyName() {
    cout << "omer";
}
```

**try.cpp (main file):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "printmyname.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    printMyName();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
undefined reference to `printMyName()`
```

What's is the problem?

Comment: I suggest that you complete compile error messages. You will get better advice.

Comment: what is your platform?

Comment: you should give the command you used so far to compile your code. Your code is fine, it's how you compile it that there's a problem!

Comment: I using dev C++. I used a seperated source files. Now I added them all to one project and now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undefine reference has nothing to do with your header file in this case. It means the linker cannot find the implementation of `printMyName` which is in `printmyname.cpp`. If you are using `g++`, you should try:

```
g++ try.cpp printmyname.cpp -o yourBinaryName
```

If you are using a makefile, you should add dependency(printmyname.cpp) correctly for try.cpp.

Edit:

As @zmo suggest in his comment:

you can also do it through a two times compilation (more suitable with Makefiles):

```
g++ -c printmyname.cpp 
g++ try.cpp printmyname.o -o yourBinaryName
```

Comment: you can also do it through a two times compilation (more suitable with Makefiles): `g++ -c printmyname.cpp` `g++ try.cpp printmyname.o -o tryprintmyname`, and give a better name than `a.out` :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you need to add the printmyname.cpp to your project too.
Consider adding an [include guard to your header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards)

```
#ifndef PRINTMYNAME_INCLUDED 
#define PRINTMYNAME_INCLUDED 

void printMyName();

#endif
```

You will also need to move the `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` from the try.cpp to the printmyname.cpp file.

Answer (score -6):

You need to add code/definition in printMyName.cpp inside printMyName.h only.

```
void printMyName();
{
    cout << "omer";
}
```

Comment: Bad advice (although it would fix the issue).

Comment: the OP wants to learn how to correctly use headers in C++, and you're advicing him to do one thing that goes against modularity!

Comment: You'd also need to make it inline if you did that

Comment: @doctorlove: If the header is included in only one translation unit (cpp file), it will work without `inline` too. Still, this is a bad idea.