# How do I stop an IntelliSense PCH Warning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header, include, intellisense

A few of my header files have no includes, so I receive this message in Visual Studio 2010:

```
IntelliSense: PCH warning: cannot find a suitable header stop location.  An intellisense PCH file was not generated.
```

If I add a single header, for instance:

```
#include <iostream>
```

It disappears. How can I stop this error from showing without adding (potentially unused) include>

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When adding a .cpp file it inherits the PCH settings of the project. 
More detailed explanation of the problem [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650359/intellisense-pch-warning-can-not-find-a-suitable-header-stop-location-a-pch-file-wasnt-generated)

Solutions:

1. Add `#pragma once` at the start of the file.

It will cause your source file to be included only once in a single compilation, therefore the compiler will be satisfied and won't require additional `#include`

2. Setting your project to not use precompiled headers
3. Disable PCH usage for that one cpp file you've added, which will clear both IntelliSense and compiler warning/error.

Note! I'm including num 2, and 3 because some say it helped, but it only num 1 that did solve my case.

Comment: I... don't even remember what project of mine this error is from. I'll just open every one in VS2010 until I receive this error and can try `#pragma once`.

Comment: Only took me half a year, but I finally accepted your answer! :D

Comment: can you please explain #pragma directive ?! why it solves the problem ?

Comment: @GokulJai you can see what it means in here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once
and a discussion about its benifits in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards

Comment: Maybe this helps for headers, but it doesn't make sense to add this in a .c/.cpp file (nor does it resolve the error in such a case). Restarting VS did the trick for me (rebuilding and restarting the C++ IntelliSense parser service wasn't enough).

Comment: I already had `#pragma once` in my file. Maybe you should explain what causes this error, rather than a single potential solution to it.

Comment: @Nic Hartley, try to setting your project to not use precompiled headers. As for explanation: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650359/intellisense-pch-warning-can-not-find-a-suitable-header-stop-location-a-pch-file-wasnt-generated

Comment: Updated the answer to provide possible problem explanation and solutions

Answer (score 6):

I suppose the problem is that you have precompiled header in your project (by default "stdafx.h") and to correctly solve the problem you should add

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

at start of your header/source file.

Comment: Well, I think he should have fixed his problem more than 3 years ago now. ;)

Comment: I wrote this asnwer for other users who encounter this problem to know why this problem occurs. F.E. I had the same problem, I visited this question saw an anser that solves the problem, but I didnt know why it does, so I thinked and wrote another answer that also soves problem AND explains how it solves it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to project's property and under **C/C++ => Precompiled Headers**, find the option "Precompiled header".

Change it to "Not Using Precompiled Headers".

[image]

Comment: or also add #include "pch.h" in the beginning of your file

Answer (score 2):

Restart Visual Studio (close all active projects).

Nothing helped me except this

Comment: Better as a comment