# IntelliSense: PCH warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Some how I get IntelliSence error. How to fix it? I don't have no more suggestions in my cpp files. In h files they are. In picture error text ant code fragment.

I have tryed:

- Reboot
- Update
- Clode/ reopne solution
- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Genera -> Auto list members and Parameter inforamtion are checked

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I stop PCH warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215981/how-do-i-stop-an-intellisense-pch-warning)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added #pragma once, error disappeared, but suggestions still not showing

Comment: I ignore PCH and PDB warnings.  I don't look at the intellisense.  I concentrate on the issues shown on the Output Window.  Sometimes Intellisense can't get C++ parsing correct or it has false warnings.  Don't worry about PCH or PDB warnings.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews with this error suggestions showing disapeared. How I can get back suggestions? Without suggestions is hard to program for me