# GCC "bailing out" after giving a re declaration error where both defined and previously defined locations are the SAME?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

I got the following error:

```
In file included from generated/tandembiginteger.cpp:2:
generated/tandembiginteger.h:26: error: redefinition of `const int tandem::TandemMessageType_TandemBigInteger'
generated/tandembiginteger.h:26: error: `const int tandem::TandemMessageType_TandemBigInteger' previously defined here
generated/tandembiginteger.h:26: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

as you can see the redeclaration and the "previously" declared places are the SAME. What kind of an error is this ? How to solve it ?

Comment: Where's the source? From the error messages alone one cannot conclude the places are the same, only that they are on the same line.

Comment: Does this header file have an include guard?

Comment: @chill you are correct, that could have been the case. But it isn't. Infact there is only a single instance of `const int tandem::TandemMessageType_TandemBigInteger` in the entire codebase

Comment: @chill Also, are you saying taht it is ok to have multiple header files with same name ? taht compiles ?

Comment: @Hulk It had a header guard. But a faulty one ! someone made a copy past error ! it was like 
`#ifndef X_H_ 
#define Y_H_ `
 :O thanks for mentioning guards :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to use include guards.

Here's a discussion on SO about it: [#pragma once vs include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards)

Comment: It had a header guard. But a faulty one ! someone made a copy past error ! it was like #ifndef X_H_ #define Y_H_ :O thanks for mentioning guards :)

Comment: Which is exactly why #pragma once is considered safer. :)