# Make sure every header uses unique include guards in big project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, include-guards

In a not-so-tiny project (>100 `.h`), I want to make sure that every `.h` use different include-guards (`#ifndef XXX`).

Whenever I violate it, I want to be informed as soon as possible.

### Situation

Here is the convention I am using (semi-auto-generated, VS2015):-

**Foo.h**

```
#ifndef Foo_h__
#define Foo_h__
//....... some long code .........
#endif //Foo_h__
```

Sometimes (once per 1-4 weeks), after I created new files, copy-and-paste sources or refactor(rename) extensively, I make some mistakes about the include guard.      As a result :-

- Include guard does not match with file name anymore.
- Include guard happens to be same as another include guard in another header.

### Question

How to prevent and cure duplication of include guards?

## My poor solution

### **Solution 1:-**

```
#pragma once
```

**Disadvantage:** It is [compiler specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27649971/3577745).    I don't want my code to be compiler-dependent.

### **Solution 2:-**

(Edited, thank **Benjamin Lindley** and **Beta**.)

I may code an auto-code-generation script.
This is [a possible standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4871964/3577745):-

```
<project>_<path_part1>_..._<path_partN>_<file>_<extension>_INCLUDED
```

**Disadvantage:** It required an external script.

Comment: That second solution doesn't require Boost. It just uses the same convention that Boost uses. All it requires is a keyboard and knowledge of the path of the file you are editing.

Comment: I use a guid on the end of the file name.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley My mistake, thank.   Is the second solution it auto-generated? Can I just paste it?  I will investigate more.

Comment: @javaLover: It can certainly be auto-generated, if you have a decent text editor.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley  How about VS2015?

Comment: How about a script to verify that the variable name is correct, executed on all header files from time to time? Do you have any preference for a particular scripting language?

Comment: Just use `#pragma once`. Avoid the few (if any now) compilers that don't support it.  It's not at all compiler specific, it's just not part of the official standard.

Comment: @javaLover: I couldn't tell you. I haven't used Visual Studio as an editor in a long time.

Comment: @Beta python or PHP

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley  An expert doesn't use VS, I think it somehow implies that VS is bad ...  What IDE do you use?

Comment: If you feel that just cannot use the natural `#pragma once` solution, e.g. because you plan to use an ages old IBM compiler, well then generate UUIDs. It's ugly but it gets the job done.

Comment: @Cheers and hth.   No, I want to developer a program on modern hardware.  You mean most standard compilers use `#pragma once`?   Can you give a link/reference/evident about this?

Comment: @javalover: there's a discussion in Wikipedia. or was. probably still there. oh, i [found it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once). there's evidently a compiler called "portland group c/c++" that doesn't support.

Comment: @javaLover: I did not mean to imply that VS is bad. The main reason I don't use it is because it takes too long to start up. Presumably this start up time allows it to provide a bunch of features which I don't personally need. I use Sublime.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  I [found it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once), thank.  However, "not standard" still scares me.

Comment: the c++ standardization committee isn't into the thing about standardizing existing practice. they prefer to innovate. but if you really love java, then you love a language where *everything* is non-standard: java has a language spec, originally from Sun, but has never been standardized. so, assuming the nick reflects your background, you shouldn't be scared of *de facto* standards. ;-)

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  "isn't into the thing about standardizing existing practice" That is a valuable statement!  Where did you get this idea from? .... I just want to make sure before I believe and throw all of my code into it.  It seems to be a solution.  You can also post as answer, if you want.

Comment: i started observing the standardization process in the mid 1990s. i stopped with c++11. there are cases of existing practice being adopted, mainly via the Boost library. but mostly, the committee innovates. the original standardization in 1998 made all C++ textbooks invalid overnight. it took some years before compiler vendors and authors caught up.

Comment: And some never did.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [C++ "Modules"](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4465.pdf)? There appears to be some [support for modules in VS 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1/). Unfortunately it doesn't appear that modules made it into C++17. I think if I weren't in an all MS VS shop, I'd probably just continue with include guards for the time being and maybe use a script on code upload to check for their uniqueness if it was becoming a problem.

Comment: `#pragma once` **is** covered by the standard. Like all `#pragma` directives, it's effect is implementation defined [`[cpp.pragma]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.pragma)

Answer (score 0):

As `#pragma once` is not fully portable my advice is to run before building procedures this simple bash script:

```
find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.hpp' | xargs -n1 -d '\n' grep "#ifndef .*_H.*" | sort | uniq -cd
```

It eventually shows how many files use the same include guards and the exact include guards which is repeated by error.

Comment: anouthe command can be as this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53413237/2794395

Comment: What is your device?

Comment: WSL under Windows 10 (or native Ubuntu Linux 18.04)