# Header Guarding questions in C++

Tags: c++, header, macros

I am new to writing my own headers, but due to necessity, I must learn.

I am writing a header, and I'm trying to grok header guards. Is there a difference between having one or two underscores before and after the included header file?

Take this hypothetical example: x.h

```
//x.h
#ifndef __X_H_INCLUDED__
#define __X_H_INCLUDED__
//functions n stuff
#endif
```

versus:

```
//x.h
#ifndef _X_H_INCLUDED_
#define _X_H_INCLUDED_
//functions n stuff
#endif
```

Is one more or less right than the other? Is there a difference?

Comment: double underscores are reserved to the implementation -- using them in your own header files is undefined behavior and generally not a good idea.

Comment: Also check out `#pragma once` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards

Comment: It [seems like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33005607/4143855) having no leading underscores would be best. Why not just `X_H_INCLUDED` ?

Comment: @Anthony, pragmas are, by their very definition, non-portable. Though, of course, that's not an issue if you're happy to limit yourself to compilers that support it (I suspect that may be quite a few: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability).

Comment: @paxdiablo As per the linked question, quite a few. I usually use both `#pragma once` and include guards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per `C++11 17.6.4.3.2 Global names` (though this restriction has been around for a while):

> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

So you really should be using *neither* if you want your software to be portable though, having said that, plenty of people *do* use both varieties.

It would be "safer" to use something like `GUARD_X_H` or `X_H_INCLUDED` though, of course, you still need to be wary of clashes. You might take the Java way and end up with macros like:

```
AU_COM_POWERFIELD_DATASTRUCTURES_TREES_BALANCED_BTREE_H
```

as long as you stay below the implementation limits for macro names (which, from memory, is at least 1024 characters).

Alternatively, if you want to sacrifice portability (but not *much* portability since it's supported in a great many compilers), you could look into `#pragma once`, where you don't have to worry about coming up with unique names.

Answer (score 2):

From the 2003 C++ Standard (these rules still apply):

> 17.4.3.2.1 Global names [lib.global.names]
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to
>   the implementation:
>
> Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an
>   underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the
>   implementation for any use. 
>   Each name that begins with an underscore
>   is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global
>   namespace.165 165) Such names are also reserved in namespace ::std
>   (17.4.3.1).

Answer (score 1):

I like to follow a particular structure for include guards which matches the structure of the project.

```
#ifndef PROJECT_PATH_TO_FILE_HPP
// etc. etc.
```

So if the project is names "skittles", and the path to the header is `taste/the/rainbow.hpp` then my include guard becomes:

```
#ifndef SKITTLES_TASTE_THE_RAINBOW_HPP
// etc. etc.
```

This works pretty well, you just have to be wary of name clashes with file names and directories. For example, one file in the project root called `foo_bar.hpp`, and one at `foo/bar.hpp`. This will cause a name clash which would have to be worked around.

Another option is to use namespaces instead of paths:

```
#define PROJECT_NAMESPACE_MODULE_HPP
```

I've also seen people append the date and time the file was created, or use a UUID, to add further safety against name clashes.