# C++ .h and .cpp file separate

Tags: c++

I'm trying to separate my c++ code to one header and one cpp file, but the interpreter showing some errors.

Here is my code:

**Password.h:**

```
#ifndef PASSWORD_H
#define PASSWORD_H

class Password {
private:
    string aliasName_;
    int hashOfPassword_;
public:
    void setAliasName(string aliasName);
    void setHashOfPassword(int hashOfPassword);
    string getAliasName() { return aliasName_; }
    int getHashOfPassword() { return hashOfPassword_; }
};

#endif
```

**Password.cpp:**

```
#include <string>
#include "Password.h"

using std::string;

void Password::setAliasName(string aliasName) {
    aliasName_ = aliasName;
}
void Password::setHashOfPassword(int hashOfPassword) {
    hashOfPassword_ = hashOfPassword;
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   C2065   'aliasName_': undeclared identifier X\password.cpp  7
Error   C2511   'void Password::setAliasName(std::string)': overloaded member function not found in 'Password'  X\password.cpp  6
Error   C3646   'aliasName_': unknown override specifier    X\password.h    6
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    X\password.h    6
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'string'   X\password.h    9
Error   C3646   'getAliasName': unknown override specifier  X\password.h    11
Error   C2059   syntax error: '('   X\password.h    11
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  X\password.h    11
```

Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: You need to add `using std::string;` or use `std::string` in your header.

Comment: Have you heard of `const`?

Comment: Thank you Mats Petersson, working fine! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move `using std::string` before the declaration of your class:

```
#ifndef PASSWORD_H
#define PASSWORD_H

#include <string>

using std::string;

class Password {
…
```

and remove it from your .cpp file.

Also, you might want to use `#pragma once` instead of the traditional `#ifndef/#define/#endif` and finally you might want to make your argument and methods const when need be.

Comment: Thank you Zmo to your fast answer :)

Comment: no problem, if it helped you, don't hesitate to +1 and accept it ;-)

Comment: I thought the use of `using` in header files would be bad practice. But I think it is not really importent if it is not a library. Another thing: I didn't know that `#pragma once` is supported by GCC. The last time I searched for it, I did only see that it is an extension of VC. But [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1143936/4967497) says it is supported by all common compilers. O.o

Comment: it's relatively recent, I believe it's been added with support of C++11, so within the last 2 or 3 versions of GCC. About `using`, you need to have access to the type, so you need to do the `#include` in your header. Though it's indeed bad practice to do `using` in the header, because if the user of your library (considering it becomes a lib) might include your header in his `namespace` and pollute the namespace with a symbol from `std`. So it'd be a good idea to do the `#include`, and within the header file call the full "path" to `std::string` in your prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

To inside `Password.h`, you can then remove these two lines from `Password.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `std::` to every `string` in your header file and remember, you should never use `using` or `using namespace` there! You should also include all the headers to the file in which you use them.