# Getting class type redefinition and a few other errors

Tags: c++

I'm creating a student data management console application for a project. I created a class called Student which is storing all the data that a student needs to have, and it also has all the getters and setters associated with it. Here is how all my files are laid out:

Student.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Student {

private:
    string name;
    string id;
    string email;

    int presentation;
    int essay1;
    int essay2;
    int project;

public:
    //constructor
    //Student();
    //setters
    void set_name(string);
    void set_id(string);
    void set_email(string);
    void set_presentation(int);
    void set_essay1(int);
    void set_essay2(int);
    void set_project(int);
    //getters
    string get_name();
    string get_id();
    string get_email();
    int get_presentation();
    int get_essay1();
    int get_essay2();
    int get_project();
};
```

Student.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;


//constructor definition
/*
Student::Student(void) {
    cout << "Student created" << endl;
}
*/

//setter definition
void Student::set_name(string s) {
    name = s;
}

void Student::set_id(string s) {
    id = s;
}

void Student::set_email(string s) {
    email = s;
}

void Student::set_presentation(int a) {
    presentation = a;
}

void Student::set_essay1(int a) {
    essay1 = a;
}

void Student::set_essay2(int a) {
    essay2 = a;
}

void Student::set_project(int a) {
    project = a;
}

//getter definition
string Student::get_name() {
    return name;
}

string Student::get_id() {
    return id;
}

string Student::get_email() {
    return email;
}

int Student::get_presentation() {
    return presentation;
}

int Student::get_essay1() {
    return essay1;
}

int Student::get_essay2() {
    return essay2;
}

int Student::get_project() {
    return project;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    Student student1;
    Student student2;
    Student student3;

    student1.set_name("John");
    student2.set_name("Bob");
    student3.set_name("Carl");


    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run my program, I get, amongst others, the following errors:

> Error 1   error C2011: 'Student' : 'class' type redefinition
>
> Error 2   error C2079: 'student1' uses undefined class 'Student'
>
> Error 5   error C2228: left of '.set_name' must have class/struct/union
>
> Error 9   error C2027: use of undefined type 'Student'

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: "Amongst others" is probably where the true problem lies. Can't see anything obviously wrong with what you've posted (other than omitting header guards and writing getters/setters; neither of those things will cause this problem)

Comment: First, those are compiler errors, not runtime. Otherwise, I pasted and compiled without errors on the MS v140 compiler. Which compiler are you using? Yea, you seem to be including student.h twice in code you are not showing.

Comment: Produce a [MCVE].

Comment: Voted to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: @FlameDra: Do consider adding a `#pragma once` at the top of your header. It's evidently included twice somewhere. But not in the code you've shown.

Comment: Also, a tip: a compilation error or warning typically tells you also the **source file** where the error occurred, and the **line number** in that source file. That is useful information. The cause of the error can be anywhere before that, but usually it pinpoints things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure this is an error caused by the fact that `student.h` is included twice in a certain `.cpp` file. Thus you need to use so-called header guards to make sure the file is only included once in every `.cpp` file:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {

/* ... */

};

#endif
```

The idea behind this is that an `#include` is a preprocessor directive that results in the argument file being copied into the file where the `#include` was issued. Hence, if files A and B include `Student.h`, and file C includes both files A and B, then the declaration of `class Student` is going to end up duplicated. Hence the error. The above macros make sure that this doesn't happen.

Edit as per the question author's comment:

`#pragma once` is the same as `#ifndef .. #define #endif` but non-standard .

See [#pragma once vs include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards) for reference.

Comment: Code dump without explanation = bad answer. I suppose you couldn't find an explanation, because nothing in your code dump solves the problem? :)

Comment: _"since the student.h header is included twice"_ No it's not.

Comment: It is. Once in student.cpp, once in main.cpp

Comment: It's included just once in each TU. It's included twice overall in the whole project but header guards do literally nothing to protect from that anyway

Comment: Right, once in each TU, isnt that enough for the error to appear?

Comment: No, it isn't enough. You're confusing linker errors for compilation errors.

Comment: Doing #pragma once fixed it!

Comment: @FlameDra #pragma once is less portable from what I understand. But it's the same as my answer, just in a different shape!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit see above

Comment: Then the code in the question is not the actual code that reproduces the problem. Fact!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. I just clean and rebuild the solution and error resolved.

Comment: clean what, kindly be more specific?