# Why I cannot connect my source file to the header file?

Tags: c++

I tried to make a header called Paitent_info.h as you can see here :

```
#ifdef GUARD_Paitent_info
#define GUARD_Paitent_info

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Paitent_info {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<double> tem;
};

bool compare(const Paitent_info&, const Paitent_info&);
std::istream& read(std::istream&, Paitent_info&);
std::istream& read_tem(std::istream&, std::vector<double>&);
#endif
```

and here is Paitent_info.cpp :

```
#include "Paitent_info.h"

using std::istream; using std::vector;

bool compare(const Paitent_info& x, const Paitent_info& y)
{
    return x.name < y.name;
}


istream& read(istream& ip, Paitent_info& p)
{ // do something
    return ip;
}

istream& read_tem(istream& in, vector<double>& tem)
{ // do something
    return in;
}
```

I got many error messages from this code :

1. std::istream and std::vector has not been declared
2. Paitent_info does not name a type.
3. request for member ‘name’ in ‘x’ and 'y', which is of non-class type ‘const int’.
4. istream does not name a type.

I do not know why I got all these error messages, please help me.

Comment: btw it is patient not paitent

Comment: You include guard should be ifndef not ifdef.

Comment: Use `#pragma once` in your header instead `#ifndef` guard

Comment: @Nikita `#pragma once` is non-standard afaik

Comment: @tobi303 It is definitely non standard and serves no purpose other than saving a few keystrokes which amounts to 0 if you're using an IDE or know how to configure your text editor.

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, it's non-standard, but all major compiler supports it. It less error-prone, for me it'is the reason to use it. ["#pragma once vs include guards?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards) topic covers pros and cons of both methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got a typo in the header guard:

```
#ifdef GUARD_Paitent_info
```

should be

```
#ifndef GUARD_Paitent_info
```

Currently the guard causes the header to be included only if it already has been included. Think about that for a second ;).