# Is there a way to implement a header guard that doesn't have to be modified when the header file is renamed?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, header-files

Currently for a header file named *test_header.h* I use -

```
#ifndef TEST_HEADER_H
#define TEST_HEADER_H   
/* code */
#endif /* TEST_HEADER_H */
```

What I want is a header guard which doesn't use the file name directly. Something like (*i.e. wishful crude hypothetical solution*) -

```
#if __FILE__ not in INCLUDE_LIST
#APPEND(INCLUDE_LIST, __FILE__)
/* code */
#endif
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't _need_ to change header guard after renaming - not unless you have another file that takes over the old name.

Comment: I know, but this way I can be worry-less (sic).

Comment: You can use an identifier with a prefix plus a UUID and be even more worry-less.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis - I didn't get it; could you explain it using the _test_header.h_ example.

Comment: `#pragma once` is supported on many compilers...

Comment: Currently my team follows a strict "no pragma" coding standard (because it reduces portability). _(Maybe it is time to relook the coding standards.)_

Comment: There are `#pragma once` to include guard converters and vice versa. [Qt Creator recently used one to convert all their headers to use `#pragma once`](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/commit/39a38d5679084b515276285c044d8a27e671adb1)

Comment: @work.bin, there is a handful of pragmas that are in fact defined by standard C -- portability is not an issue for those particular pragmas.  But `#pragma once` is not among those, and I'm inclined to agree with the idea of avoiding implementation defined behavior, such as use of non-standard pragmas produces.

Comment: Create a UUID or GUID and use that as the header guard (or a hash of some sort — MD5, SHA1, SHA2, SHA3, …).  The only trick is dealing with the possibility of a leading digit; that's easily worked around (I used `H_` as a prefix).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - So the header guard macro you used was "H_<40 SHA1 chars>", i.e. did you use all 40 characters of the hash (assuming it was SHA1)?

Comment: @work.bin : near enough, yes.  As long as the content you're hashing is unique it works fine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Could you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have noted, what you use as a header guard isn't intrinsically important; it just needs to be unique across the set of headers that might ever be co-included.

You can create a UUID or GUID and use that as the header guard (or a hash of some sort — MD5, SHA1, SHA2, SHA3, …). The only trick is dealing with the possibility of a leading digit; that's easily worked around (I used `H_` as a prefix).

Mostly though, I use a name based on the file name, and don't usually rename headers often enough that it is a problem.

Here's a script called `hdrguard` that I use for generating the header guard lines for a given header file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# @(#)$Id: hdrguard.sh,v 1.8 2016/05/09 18:41:57 jleffler Exp $
#
# Generate #ifndef sequence to guard header against multiple inclusion

arg0=$(basename $0 .sh)

usestr="Usage: $arg0 [-bdfhimV] header.h [...]"

usage()
{
    echo "$usestr" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

help()
{
    echo "$usestr"
    echo
    echo "  -b  Use base name of file for guard"
    echo "  -d  Use _DOT_H after name (instead of _H)"
    echo "  -f  Use specified path name of file for guard (default)"
    echo "  -h  Print this help message and exit"
    echo "  -i  Omit _INCLUDED after name"
    echo "  -m  Generate MD5 hash value as header guard"
    echo "  -V  Print version information and exit"
    exit 0
}

opt_incl=yes
opt_base=no
opt_dot=no
opt_md5=no
while getopts bdfhimV opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    (b) opt_base=yes;;
    (d) opt_dot=yes;;
    (f) opt_base=no;;
    (h) help;;
    (i) opt_incl=no;;
    (m) opt_md5=yes;;
    (V) echo "$arg0: HDRGUARD Version "'$Revision: 1.8 $ ($Date: 2016/05/09 18:41:57 $)' | rcsmunger; exit 0;;
    (*) usage;;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

[ $# -eq 0 ] && usage

for i in "$@"
do
    if [ $opt_base = yes ]
    then i=$(basename $i)
    fi
    if [ $opt_dot = yes ]
    then i=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/\.h$/_dot_h/')
    fi
    i=$(echo $i | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | tr -s '/+.-' '____' | sed 's/^_//')
    if [ $opt_incl = yes ]
    then
        case "$i" in
        (*_INCLUDED)
            : OK;;
        (*)
            i="${i}_INCLUDED";;
        esac
    fi
    if [ $opt_md5 = yes ]
    then
        tmp=$(mktemp ./hdrgrd.XXXXXXXX)
        trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15 
        echo "$i.$(isodate compact)" > "$tmp"
        i=$(md5 "$tmp" | sed 'y/abcdef/ABCDEF/; s/\([^ ]*\) .*/H_\1/')
        rm -f "$tmp"
        trap 0 1 2 3 13 15
    fi
    echo
    echo "#ifndef $i"
    echo "#define $i"
    echo
    echo "#endif /* $i */"
    echo
done
```

It doesn't have code for SHA1, SHA2 or SHA3 — it optionally uses MD5 (in the form of a command `md5`). It would not be very hard to add support for alternative hashing algorithms.  It doesn't require the file to exist.

Example uses:

```
$ hdrguard header.h

#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

#endif /* HEADER_H_INCLUDED */

$ hdrguard -m header.h

#ifndef H_6DC5070597F88701EB6D2CCAACC73383
#define H_6DC5070597F88701EB6D2CCAACC73383

#endif /* H_6DC5070597F88701EB6D2CCAACC73383 */

$
```

I frequently use it from within `vim`, typing a command such as `!!hdrguard %` while the cursor is on an empty line to generate a header guard suitable for the header I'm editing.  That's why it generates the blank lines top and bottom, too.

The command uses scripts `isodate` and `rcsmunger`. With the argument `compact`, the `isodate` command is equivalent to:

```
date +'%Y%m%d.%H%M%S'
```

The complete command supports a number of alternative formats and is more succinct than having to type the `date` command out everywhere.  You're entirely at liberty to forego the use of a separate script and to just embed the expansion shown into `hdrguard`.  Indeed, you could use just `date` and it would be OK; it is just seed material for the hashing operation to make the data being hashed unique.

```
$ isodate compact
20161228.185232
$
```

The `rcsmunger` command just converts RCS ID strings into a format I prefer for reporting version information:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -p
#
# @(#)$Id: rcsmunger.pl,v 1.9 2015/11/02 23:54:32 jleffler Exp $
#
# Remove the keywords around the values of RCS keywords

use strict;
use warnings;

# Beware of RCS hacking at RCS keywords!
# Convert date field to ISO 8601 (ISO 9075) notation
s%\$(Date:) (\d\d\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) \$%\$$1 $2-$3-$4 $5 \$%go;
# Remove keywords
s/\$([A-Z][a-z]+|RCSfile): ([^\$]+) \$/$2/go;
```

For example:

```
$ hdrguard -V
hdrguard: HDRGUARD Version 1.8 (2016-05-09 18:41:57)
$
```

You can regard the printing of version information as old-school version control; it has to be done differently if you use a DVCS such as `git`, which is one reason I've not done a wholesale migration to `git` for my personal software collection.

Answer (score 4):

You can name the header guards whatever you like.

- If your header is related to a certain topic, name it after that i.e. `LIST_OPERATIONS`
- Omit the guards and write a script that inserts them based on the current file name. Run this script as part of your build process before compiling. (Remember to either create a modified copy or remove the includes after the build, otherwise you end up with a lot of include guards in your header)
- Depending on the compilers that should be used for your project, they might support the `#pragma once` approach.

Comment: Your script can also delete old include guards if they have distinctive format, or do nothing if the right guards are already present

Answer (score 3):

[`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)

It's very portable, being well-supported by all major compilers, and by 13 out of 14 compilers ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability)).

Also check out [#pragma once vs include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143936/3425536).

Comment: But programs that use `#pragma once` nevertheless are not strictly conforming.  If your objective is to write portable code then you will not use it, the proportion of major compilers supporting it notwithstanding.