# Expected identifier or '(' parse issue in C language in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, pointers, struct, stack

I was working on pop and push methods on the stack. Actually in this code I am creating dynamic array using pointers and malloc function. Then I was trying to add or delete elements to dynamic array with pop and push methods.But I getting the error in the question. I can't see any error in the code. Can you help me?

Here my main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main_header.h"
stack * init(){
    stack *s = (stack *) malloc(sizeof(stack));
    s->items = NULL;
    s->top = 0;
    s->count = 2;
    return s;
}

int pop(stack *s){
    if(s->items == NULL){
        printf("Items is empty.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(s->top<=s->count/4){
        int *items2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*s->count/2);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < (s->count/2); i++){
            items2[i] = s->items[i];
        }
        free(s->items); // burada "dizi" adındaki dizimiz dizi2 ile aynı yeri gösterdiğinde önceki 2 elemanlık dizi lost in space olacak bunu önlemek için free(dizi) diyerek o 2 elemanı bellekten siliyoruz.
        s->items = items2;
        s->count /= 2;

    }
    return s->items[--s->top];
}

void push(int a, stack *s){
    if(s->items == NULL){
        s->items = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    }
    if(s->top>=s->count){
        int *items2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*s->count*2);
        for (int i = 0; i < s->count; i++)
            items2[i] = s->items[i];
        free(s->items); // burada "dizi" adındaki dizimiz dizi2 ile aynı yeri gösterdiğinde önceki 2 elemanlık dizi lost in space olacak bunu önlemek için free(dizi) diyerek o 2 elemanı bellekten siliyoruz.
        s->items = items2;
        s->count *= 2;
        
    }
    s->items[s->top++] = a;
}

void getItems(stack *s){
    printf("count: %d\n", s->count);
    for (int i = 0; i < s->top; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", s->items[i]);
    }
}
```

main_header.h file

```
#ifndef main
#define main

struct s {
    int count;
    int top;
    int *items;
    
};
typedef struct s stack;
stack * init(void);
int pop(stack *);
void getItems(stack *);
void push(int, stack *);
#endif
```

test_stack.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main_header.h"


int main(){
    
    stack *s1 = init();
    
    stack *s2 = init();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        push(i*10, s1);
    }
    
    getItems(s1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        push(pop(s1), s2);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not certain but your header looks suspicious.  How about trying `#ifndef main_H
#define main_H` or similar.

Comment: As @PhillipMills noted: your header guard in `main_header.h` defines a macro `main` as an empty string.  Your `int main()` line becomes `int ()` which is invalid syntax.  Make sure your header guards are unique and not going to be confused with functions etc.  I'd be using `MAIN_HEADER_H` or `MAIN_HEADER_H_INCLUDED` as the header guard.  See also my `hdrguard` script in my answer to [Is there a way to implement a header guard that doesn't have to be modified when the header is renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41365842/15168).

Comment: Thank you so much @PhillipMills and Jonathan Leffler. I renamed my main file to "stack_arr". In main_header I wrote "ifndef stack_arr" and "define stack_arr" instead of "ifdef main" and "define main". Thus, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `#define main` in “main_header.h”, the code `int main(){` in “test_stack.c” is replaced by `int (){`. This causes the syntax error that the compiler (not Xcode) reports.

Do not use `main` in “main_header.h” as an indicator for whether the header file has been included already. Use some other name that you will not use for anything else, such as `main_h` or `main_header_h`.

(Clang is the compiler. Xcode is the overall integrated development environment that facilitates use of the compiler, organizes your projects files, opens editors, maintains your project options, and so on.)