# Do comments prevent a header guard optimization?

Tags: c, optimization, comments, c-preprocessor, header-files

Does C compiler cache a header file and parse it only once if the file starts with a comment?

```
// Some comment
#ifndef HEADER_GUARD
#define HEADER_GUARD

#endif
```

The question is about compilers, that can cache headers to not parse them more than once.

Comment: This is implementation dependent. The compiler may or may not cache this information. Some ocmpilers have the `#pragma once` that may be more efficient than header guards. Aso read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this optimization is done. `gcc` documents it quite explicitly here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html

Basically, if you have a well-written include guard, `gcc` won't touch the header twice. And a comment outside of the include guard does not stop the optimization (it would be worthless otherwise with all the license comments that precede virtually all open-source header files).