# Trying to put two classes in separate files in the same namespace, but only the first #included class works

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

In C++, I am trying to put two classes in separate files into the same namespace.

I get two errors in `main` saying that the class `Head` is not in the namespace `Names`, and that `days` is not declared in this scope.

It seems that when I switch the order of the `#include` statements, the class that doesn't work flip flops between the two. From what I've read, the namespace should open again when the second file is included, and put the second class into the namespace, but it isn't working.

Why does the order of which one I include matter as to which works? What can I do to make both classes be a part of the same namespace, while keeping them in separate header files?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dy.hpp"
#include "dayyear.hpp"

int main(){
   int d=2;
   int y=5;
   Names::Dy yup(y,d);
   Names::Head days(y,d);
   days.print();
   yup.print();
   return 0;  
}
```

dayyear.hpp

```
#ifndef DY_H
#define DY_H

namespace Names{
   class Head{
      int year;
      int day;
   public:
      Head();
      Head(int y, int d);
      void print();
      void change(int y, int d);
   };
}
#endif
```

dayyear.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dayyear.hpp"

Names::Head::Head(){
   day=0;
   year=0;  
}

Names::Head::Head(int y, int d){
   day=d;
   year=y;  
}

void Names::Head::print(){
   std::cout<<day<<", "<<year<<std::endl;
}

void Names::Head::change(int y, int d){
   year=y;
   day=d;  
}
```

dy.hpp

```
#ifndef DY_H
#define DY_H

namespace Names{
   class Dy{
      int year;
      int day;
   public:
      Dy();
      Dy(int y, int d);
      void print();
      void change(int y, int d);
   };
}
#endif
```

dy.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dy.hpp"

Names::Dy::Dy(){
   day=0;
   year=0;  
}

Names::Dy::Dy(int y, int d){
   day=d;
   year=y;  
}

void Names::Dy::print(){
   std::cout<<day<<", "<<year<<std::endl;
}

void Names::Dy::change(int y, int d){
   year=y;
   day=d;  
}
```

Comment: You use the guard `DY_H` in two different files. Including one of those files will prevent the other from being included.

Comment: You can change `dy.hpp`'s guard to `DY_HPP`

Comment: This is why I use `#pragma once`; I've been bit by forgetting to change header guards more than once, and all the compilers I care about support it

Comment: If you want to use a `#define` guard, then you should consider a naming like `<PROJECT>_<PATH>_<FILE>_H_`.

Comment: @Justin: not all C++ compilers support `#pragma once`, though

Comment: @Justin [Not everyone agrees with using `#pragma once`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards/34884735#34884735)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I never said that everyone agrees. I'm merely remarking that the OP could consider using it. It's not fit for every purpose / company, but it's a decision that has to be made (whether to use `#pragma once` or header guards)

Comment: @Justin I guess I misread your comment. I had the impression that it was advocating that `#pragma once` was the superior solution, but on a second read it seems reasonable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry about that; on a second read I could see that the comment might seem like I was advocating. *Natural language* is so ambiguous

Comment: @Justin I think better solution is to have proper IDE or editor that generates guards properly

Comment: @Slava It's a good solution, but I still forget because I copy-paste a header to create a new header that's similar, but forget to change the guard. If I worked at a company that required me to use header guards, though, that's absolutely what I'd do, and just suck it up and deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because both dayyear.hpp and dy.hpp have:

```
#ifndef DY_H
#define DY_H
.....
#endif
```

dayyear.hpp should have:

```
#ifndef DAYYEAR_H
#define DAYYEAR_H
.....
#endif
```

The preprocessor only regards the first appearance of the same `#infdef/#define/#endif` construct, all the subsequent ones are replaced with empty code.  That is why the order of `#include` statements matters.