# Names used for include guards?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, include-guards

Are there any guidelines people tend to follow when selecting a name for their include guard? I don't understand why the name for the **.h** file will slightly differ from the name used in the include guard. For example, I have seen sphere.h and then `#ifndef SPHERE_H_`. Could I just as easily have used `SPHERE_` or do the names have to match? Are the underscores also necessary?

Comment: The argument over good names and possible collisions (what if you have two files with the same names in different directories that are part of the same project?) is part of the reason many people prefer `#pragma once`. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards).

Comment: For `sphere.h`, I use `#ifndef GUARD_sphere_h`.

Comment: At the least, don't use names containing double-underscores or names starting with an underscore and followed by an uppercase letter - both are reserved.

Comment: Underscores are not necessary, but do not use one at the beginning or two in a row anywhere. More on that in [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: This isn't known as an `#ifndef`, but as a *header guard* or *include guard*

Comment: I used to use a GUID, e.g. `H123e4567_e89b_12d3_a456_426655440000`. I had a little program to generate them in wholesale lots. Now I just use `#pragma once`. Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @JiveDadson — `#pragma once` can fail, and it’s not standard C++.

Comment: @Pete Becker -  There is only one major(ish) compiler that I know of which does not support #pragma once. It is not one that I need to worry about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pick a good name for a header guard, consider these points:

1) the name has to be unique, so make it long and specific. That can usually be accomplished by including things like project name, module name, file name and file extension.

2) make sure you don't use names reserved for the implementation. So, names starting with underscore followed by a capital letter are out, as are names containing double underscore, names ending in _t and a few more.

3) make the name make sense to human readers. So don't just generate a UUID and use that.

4) convention dictates that you use all uppercase for macros to distinguish them from ordinary variables.

Underscores are not *needed*, *as such*, but since you cannot use spaces in macro names, underscores serve as a good alternative to keep things readable.

So, IMHO, a good guard name for a file foo.h in a submodule bar inside project baz is: BAZ_BAR_FOO_H .

Comment: The main problem with GUID's is that they end up being Gnot-UIDs when somebody copies the header and modifies the C++ code without updating the GUID. That's not unusual when implementing sibling classes.

Comment: @MSalters I did not recommend using GUIDs, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern compiler support the `#pragma once` directive that could be used instead. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

Comment: However, this pragma is not yet standardized

Comment: And it's always worth noting that it is not standardized because there are a few outstanding cases that `#pragma once` cannot handle.

Comment: `#pragma once` doesn't work if the same header is copied into different directories. *Include guards* also can also fail this way, if the "same header" is two different versions. But the #pragma failure is likely to be faster and more visible.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing about the symbols used for include guards is that they are unique.  That means that not only do the include guards for every header file (including any library headers your project may be using) need to be unique, they must also not clash with any other symbols used anywhere in your project.

There are a couple common ways people go about ensuring uniqueness:

1) Use something like `<PROJECT_NAME>_<FILE_NAME>` (i.e. `MYPROJECT_SPHERE_H`)

Including your project name will help ensure your include guard doesn't clash with that of another "sphere.h" you include from some library.  Using the file name and extension makes it easy to create include guards when adding a new header to your project and makes it very unlikely that name will be used anywhere else in the project (for a variable, function, etc.).

2) Use a UUID (i.e. `GUARD_0be96322_7238_49d2_a967_e8fd9907cca1`)

This is a very safe approach, since UUIDs are *extremely* unlikely to ever collide.  It is harder to read though, and means you have to dig out your UUID generator whenever you create a new file.

Comment: Some programmers’ editors can generate include guards with UUIDs.

Comment: Header guards containing UUIDs are a pain to read though and don't convey any meaning about what's being guarded.