# Clangd code completion not working with IPP (TPP) files in VS Code

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-code, code-completion, clangd

When I separate a template class definition into an HPP file and a IPP (TPP) file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54363250/15826299), I cannot take advantage of the code completion feature offered by *clangd*. **Is there a way to "inform" the IPP (TPP) file about its corresponding header file?**