# How to deal with pragma once?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, c++17, qt-creator

To my understanding Visual Studio C++ projects use `#pragma once` in the very top of header files to prevent multiple inclusion.

And the same is achieved, in Qt Creator projects, with

```
#ifndef   FILE_H
#define   FILE_H
// Code here
#endif
```

Let's say I got a Visual Studio project and I want to play with Qt Creator. How to deal with the `#pragma once` issue?

If possible I don't want to edit all header files.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `#pragma once` is supported by Qt Creator.

Comment: `#pragma once` (or header guards) are processed (at least primarily) by the compiler, not the IDE.

Comment: What problem does `#pragma once` cause? please explain

Comment: Depending on your compiler or C++ version, `#pragma once` can be ignored, or the compiler can complain that the `#pragma` is not supported.

Comment: And even if `#pragma once` is supported it can be fooled by a sufficiently complicated directory structure. Here's a good discussion: [#pragma once vs include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143936/pragma-once-vs-include-guards) Don't stop at the first answer. There are a number of conflicting views and to really get the issues, you have to read  down several answers.

Comment: Never heard about a real world problem with pragma once the last >10 years. And if still a preprocessor ist not able to see that ../bla/xy.h is the same as ../../blub/bla/xy.h... Not really in 2021 I believe :-) There are some really obscure but also outdated compilers, which had that problem... ok, but long time ago! And as you already have pragma once in your code, simply leave it as it is as long it did not make trouble, If you need to change, do it if the problem really occurs, but not before!

Comment: @Klaus I admit you'd really have to you'd have to work at it. It's about as likely as someone cut-n-pasting or otherwise using the same include guard identifier.

Comment: +1 never seen issues with pragma once so far, and using it in few large projects on Linux with gcc. If ever problem occurs, only then it is worh to add standars include guard, otherwise worth to use pragma once by default.

Comment: It almost seems `#pragma once` is better than the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, really, `#pragma once` originates from Microsoft C++, but nowadays it is supported by at least two another most used modern C++ compilers (i.e GCC and clang). So you should not have a problems with it.

Comment: To elaborate on this, `#pragma once` is [supported by several compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability).