# Why is a friend function not treated as a member of a namespace of a class it was declared in without additional declaration?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, friend

Suppose we have a class `foo` from a namespace `space` which declares a `friend` function named `bar`, which is later on defined, like so:

```
namespace space {
    struct foo {
        friend void bar(foo);
    };
}

namespace space {
    void bar(foo f) { std::cout << "friend from a namespace\n"; }
}
```

To my understanding, `friend void bar(foo);` *declares* `bar` to be a free function *inside `space`* taking a `foo` by value. To use it, we can simply do:

```
auto f = space::foo();
bar(f);
```

My understanding is that we don't have to say `space::bar`, because ADL will see that `bar` **is defined in the same `namespace` as `foo`** (its argument) and allow us to omit the full name qualification. Nonetheless, **we are permitted to qualify it**:

```
auto f = space::foo();
space::bar(f);
```

which works (and should work) exactly the same.

Things started to get weird when I introduced other files. Suppose that we move the class and the declaration to `foo.hpp`:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_FOO_HPP
#define PROJECT_FOO_HPP

namespace space {
    struct foo {
        friend void bar(foo);
    };
}

#endif //PROJECT_FOO_HPP
```

and the definitions to `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace space {
    void bar(foo f) { std::cout << "friend from a namespace\n"; }
}
```

notice that all I did was I *moved* (didn't change any code) stuff to a `.hpp`-`.cpp` pair.

What happened then? Well, assuming that we `#include "foo.hpp"`, we still can do:

```
auto f = space::foo();
bar(f);
```

**but, we are no longer able to do:**

```
auto f = space::foo();
space::bar(f);
```

This fails saying that: `error: 'bar' is not a member of 'space'`, which is, well, confusing. I am fairly certain that `bar` **is** a member of `space`, unless I misunderstood something heavily. What's also interesting is the fact that if we additionally declare (again!) `bar`, but *outside* of `foo`, it works. What I mean by that is if we change `foo.hpp` to this:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_FOO_HPP
#define PROJECT_FOO_HPP

namespace space {
    struct foo {
        friend void bar(foo);
    };
    
    void bar(foo); // the only change!
}

#endif //PROJECT_FOO_HPP
```

it now works.

Is there something with header / implementation files that alters the expected (at least for me) behaviour? Why is that? Is this a bug? I am using **gcc version 10.2.0 (Rev9, Built by MSYS2 project)**.

Comment: Without the additional declaration outside of the `struct`, it's not *just* a `friend`, it's a **hidden** `friend`.  That hidden friend's declaration is not injected into the namespace.

Comment: @Eljay I was aware of the term *hidden friend*, but I had no idea it carried some actual, semantic meaning. Is it an actual term from the standard or there is a set or rules that is just interpreted as referring to *a hidden friend*?

Comment: Ehmm, unrelated, but you may consider `#pragma once` instead of traditional define guards

Comment: @MatG I am aware of `#pragma once`, of the fact that it is non-standard and of the fact that despite the previous statement, almost every relevant compiler supports it, but thank you for the comment :)

Comment: Zwol, the person who originally made `#pragma once` in GCC, advises not to use it.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884735/4641116

Comment: @Eljay Wow, I'll stop using it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a slight subtlety that the `friend` declaration, while it doesn't require a previous declaration of the function or class your class is befriending, does not make the function visible for lookup except via ADL.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend):

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within a class or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers X) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided - see namespaces for details.

This is why you're able to find `bar(f)` (performs ADL) but not `space::bar(f)` (fully qualifying the name means ADL is not invoked).

Calling code that doesn't find `bar` via ADL needs to see a declaration. In the version where everything is in one file, calling code will see the entire definition of `space::foo`. When you split it into an HPP and a CPP file, calling code only sees the friend declaration which provides limited accessibility.

As you identified, if you want to make the function visible via ordinary lookup, put a declaration of `foo` in "foo.hpp":

```
#ifndef PROJECT_FOO_HPP
#define PROJECT_FOO_HPP

namespace space {
    struct foo {
        friend void bar(foo);
    };

    void bar(foo); // Now code that includes foo.hpp will see a declaration for bar
}

#endif //PROJECT_FOO_HPP
```

Comment: "*In your first example, calling code will see the entire definition of `space::foo`*" - can you elaborate on that? Why would it see any definitons, since I am only `#include`ing `foo.hpp"`? I don't quite get the second paragraph of your answer.

Comment: @Fureeish By "first example" I mean your very first block of code, from before you split `namespace space` into separate files.

Comment: Everything makes sense now, thanks. The quote from cppreference explains everything very clearly. Thank you!