# clang-check header file with #pragma once leads to redefinition errors

Tags: c++, clang

To check header files with `clang-check`, it is often suggested to just pass the header to `clang-check`. However, this does not work well when the header contains a `#pragma once` guard, because the compiler thinks it is in the main file:

```
/some/path/foo.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [-Wpragma-once-outside-header]
#pragma once
        ^
```

It might seem to be sufficient to disable the warning by adding `-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header` to `compile_flags.txt` (or the [compilation database](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html)), but there may be other *errors* caused by the compiler ignoring the `#pragma once` guard in a main file. This is best explained with an example.

Consider the following mini-project structure:

`foo.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

class Foo
{
    Foo();
};

#include "foo.hpp"
```

`foo.hpp`:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "foo.h"

Foo::Foo()
{
    // do something...
}
```

`compiler_flags.txt`:

```
-xc++
```

Then running `clang-check foo.h` leads to these errors:

```
/some/path/foo.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [-Wpragma-once-outside-header]
#pragma once
        ^
In file included from ./foo.h:8:
In file included from ./foo.hpp:3:
./foo.h:3:7: error: redefinition of 'Foo'
class Foo
      ^
./foo.hpp:3:10: note: './foo.h' included multiple times, additional include site here
#include "foo.h"
         ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
Error while processing /some/path/foo.h.
```

I think the problem could be solved by handling header files differently. An intermediate C++ source file that just includes the given header file could be created and used as an "entry point" for the analysis. Maybe this can be configured somehow?

Comment: does the same thing happen if you were to define header guards instead of `#pragma once` ?  `#ifndef FOO_H #define FOO_H ... #endif `

Comment: The dev who implemented `#pragma once` recommends using header guards instead.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884735/4641116)

Comment: @NeonFire Using include guards instead of `#pragma once` works, but replacing them in a large project where they cause no other problems is not convenient for us.

Comment: @Eljay I don't think a former GCC dev's opinion is relevant for clang. None of the problems discussed in their recommendation applies here.