# problem with accesing protected methods in friend class

Tags: c++, class, friend

I'm starting a new project and I have trouble with accessing protected methods of `Organism` inside `World` class. I suppose there must be some error with my definition of `World` being a friend of `organism`. I tried calling some method from Organism inside World, but the compiler says that it is inaccessible. The method was of course set as protected, so only derived classes and friends could call them.

World.h:

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <iostream>
using std::vector;  

#include <map>
using std::map;
#include "Organism.h"
#pragma once
class World
{
private:
    map<int, std::shared_ptr<Organism>> organims_map;
    vector <std::shared_ptr<Organism>> animals_vector;
    int x_size, y_size; 
    void initiate_aniamals();
public:
    World();
    World(int x, int y);
    void make_turn();

    
};
```

Organism.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "World.h"
class Organism
{
    friend class World;
private:
    int strength, vigor;
    int x_pos, y_pos;
    float level;
protected:
    int get_vigor() const;
    virtual void action() = 0 ;
    virtual void collision() = 0;
    /// <summary>
    /// compares animals by their vigor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other organism"></param>
    /// <returns>which animal has higher vigor</returns>
    bool operator<(const Organism& other_organism);
};
```

Then In file world.cpp i try to define method make_turn():

```
void World::make_turn()
{
    //stable sort animals by their vigor
    std::stable_sort(begin(this->animals_vector), end(this->animals_vector),
        [](const Organism& organism_1, const Organism& organism_2)
        {
            return  organism_1.get_vigor(); //
        });
```

I get error in line:

```
 return  organism_1.get_vigor();
```

says that function get_vigor is inacessible.

Comment: you should add the actual error message to your question

Comment: Perhaps due to the circular inclusion you have? If you don't include the header files in each other and only have forward declarations of the classes, does it work then?

Comment: It looks like you could remove `#include "Organism.h"` from `World.h` and `#include "World.h"` from `Organism.h` and forward declare `Organism` and `World` instead.

Comment: The `std::shared_ptr<Organism>` begin passed to your comparison lambda is not an `Organism` for the `const Organism&` parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the fact that `#pragma once` was not at the beginning of `World.h` But after including `Organism.h`. That leads to tons of weird errors including the fact that despite being friends of `Organism`, `World` couldn't use its private methods.

This is correct:

```
#pragma once
#include "Organism.h"
```

This, however is absolutely not:

```
#include "Organism.h"
#pragma once
```

Comment: `#pragma once` is not standard.  For my compiler, it can appear anywhere in the header file and it is effective.  Zachary Weinberg, the creator of `#pragma once`, advises [against](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884735/4641116) using it, and recommends include guards instead which are supported by the C++ standard.