# How to handle template related compilation errors

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

Recently I met a C2908 error:

> explicit specialization xxx has already been instantiated

The reason is that, for our `MyClient` class, we have the operator `less` specifically defined  as to compare using the member property `ClientSerialNumber`; after a wrong header file included, the C2908 error appears.

```
// Specialization of the Standard C++ predicate less. It is critical to have
// it for correct comparison of objects of Myclient class
template <>
struct less<Myclient>
{
    bool operator()(const Myclient& lhs,
               const Myclient& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.ClientSerialNumber < rhs.ClientSerialNumber;
    }
};
```

In normal compilation error, the line of error shows a type mismatch or a grammar error. The compilation of templates are hidden behind the hundreds of `#include`. Such error is quite sneaky -- from the compilation error, I only knew semantically what leads to the error, but could not find which line introduced it easily. The error was introduced by a complex merge, in the end I caught the culprit -- a `#include` line which works in a branch but conflicts after merging -- by adding files one by one.

Honestly I don't know exactly how the error happened yet.
We use MSVS, always have the `#pragma once` protection at the beginning of each header file.

Any suggestions on how to debug, fix, or even better, prevent such template related compilation errors please?

Comment: In the header than cannot abide the sneaky header, `#ifdef GUARD_SNEAKY_H` `#error Cannot include sneaky.h` `#endif`

Comment: we always have the `#pragma once` protection.

Comment: MSVC just doesn't have the best diagnostic messages. A reasonable compiler would show where exactly the previous definition is. [see](https://godbolt.org/z/M1exYsn7f).

Comment: For what it's worth, Zack Weinberg (zwol) the developer who created `#pragma once` discourages their use: ["should never be used"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884735/4641116).  That was a while ago, maybe those concerns have all be resolved since then.  I wish there was a `#once` in the standard, because gcc/clang's `#pragma once` has different semantics from Microsoft's cl.exe's `#pragma once`.

Comment: @Eljay yeah that's a long debated topic. let's say i make much much much more errors than `#pragma once`, my focus is rather the complexity introduced by templates in compilation time.

Comment: I suspect than "regular" `less<Myclient>`is instantiated before the declaration of the specialization... Can you declare that specialization just after `MyClient` definition?

Comment: @Jarod42 the specialization is just after the `MyClient` class definition, in the same file, just wrapped inside `std` namespace.

Comment: Could you have forward declaration of MyClient, (before an instantiated `std::map<MyClient, T>`)?

Comment: @Jarod42 Before an instantiation of `std::set<MyClient>`, when shall I use a forward declaration (of `MyClient`), when I shall I just use `#include <mypath/MyClient.h>`?

Comment: I meant a problematic forward declaration instead of the `#include`.

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry i don't get it, how could a forward declaration cause the compilation trouble? semantically i don't understand the effect...

Comment: If you instantiate (the generic) `std::less<MyClient>` (and so it requires forward declaration of `MyClient`) and the specialization `std::less<MyClient>` (so with full definition of `MyClient`), your program would be ill-formed NDR, mostly as ODR-violation.